# Что делать, если коллеги, которые тоже члены SO, вынуждены использовать тот же компьютер?

Tags: обсуждение, профиль-участника

У нас глобальный переезд и объединение организаций. На какое-то время (а всё временное часто бывает надолго) все компьютеры упадут в одну наносеть. Ладно бы только это, но придётся даже нескольким сотрудникам использовать один и тот же компьютер.
Я это к чему: я привык использовать много машин (большинство - для счёта, но, пока считает, можно и почту прочесть, и в SO залезть), теперь на нескольких из них будут посажены сотрудники (некоторых я впервые вижу), у которых тоже есть членство в SO. Это не будет рассматриваться как мультоводство?

Comment: `которые тоже члены SO` — участники, Виктор, участники...

Comment: @Arhad Хм.. Мне, на четверть биологу, слово "член" абсолютно ни на что не намекает. Видимо, профессиональный пофигизм :)

Comment: Просто однажды вернётся Grundy и вас всех объединят.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Мультоводство само по себе здесь не запрещено.

Так что даже если будет, вам скорее всего ничего не грозит. Проблемы будут, если заподозрят в **нарушении правил с помощью мультов**, вроде взаимонакруток голосами или обхода блокировок аккаунта (за прочие нарушения, с целью эти же нарушения продолжать).

Но все эти сценарии предполагают злой умысел. Если вы просто обычные участники Stack Overflow на русском, обитающие здесь по всем правилам и не причинающие неудобств соседям, вам не о чем беспокоиться.

Comment: Ну так он как раз и спросил, не будет ли это рассматриваться как накрутка. Потому что есть пачка разных пользователей с одинаковым ip, которые вполне могут голосовать друг за друга.

Comment: @Qwertiy ТС поставил галочку, видимо, я ответил на его вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Почти все компании используют [NAT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT) и имеют один публичный IP-адрес на офис, регион или даже на страну. Так что обращения со всех компьютеров вашей организации всегда выглядели как обращения с одного адреса. Беспокоиться не о чем.