# Прекратите редактировать мои «хрен» и «фиг»! >:(

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, нытьё

Не первый раз уже замечаю за модераторами подобную хрень. У нас тут не официально-деловой стиль, а подобные слова не считаются нецензурными. Нечего делать из сайта какую-то унылую фигню, в которой не место разговорщине — она никак не мешает выполнять сайту его основную задачу.

Comment: Речь идёт про комментарии или вопросы/ответы?

Comment: @AK в первую очередь про комментарии, что лишь добавляет фиговости ситуации

Comment: Эм.. А можно ссылки, что именно отредактировано?

Comment: @Qwertiy [#comment1291151_813571](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813571/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-kevinscript#comment1291151_813571) Если у меня за три часа память не побилась, там было «Хрен знает как запускать», в котором я не вижу ничего плохого

Comment: @Qwertiy а вот ещё полазил и наткнулся на [«чепуху» (если правильно помню), заменённую на «странное»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813233/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-20170703/813248#comment1290407_813233) — это уже совсем чепуха какая-то

Comment: Воспринимайте это как автозамену и не парьтесь ... лучше автозамена, чем автобан :)

Comment: да мне вообще как-то раз "ты" на "Вы" поправили, по сравнению с этим, товарищи, ваши эмоции и разговорщина это вообще преступление за которое должна выдаваться путёвка в котёл)

Comment: @yolosora про ты/вы я тоже подумывал поныть, но было лень)

Comment: @yolosora, в комментарии? Сомневаюсь. В таком случае ты можешь просто поправить ещё раз.

Comment: Тоже замечаю что мои коментарии удаляют когда смотрю старые ответы или вопросы

Comment: Действительно странно. На англоязычных сайтах SE аналогичное слово "crap" употребляется вполне свободно, в том числе и самими администраторами.  Не понимаю в чем необходимость такой жесткой цензуры лексики.

Comment: @Duoxx, комментарии могут удаляться по разным причинам. Но лично я стараюсь переносить обсуждения в чат, по возможности.

Comment: data point: тревога «невежливый и оскорбительный» на ответе, который такие слова как  "жидокодер" содержал помечена как "спорная". То есть у кого-то есть сомнения, что такие слова не стоит в ответе на вопрос по программированию использовать.

Comment: Я сильно против подобных слов. У людей данные слова несут разную эмоциональноую окраску. Например, "хрен". Для меня  это почти что мат. Когда я встречаю такое слово на этом замечательном ресурсе, мне сразу становится грустно :( И я помечаю такой комментарий как "оскорбительный или невежливый"

Comment: @VladSpirin как показала практика, шанс перехода он "хрен" к мату достаточно высок. Ну и опять же, индивидуальный порог чувствительности у всех разный. Лично меня (как человека, а не как модератора) употребление "хрен" в качестве эфемизма *сильно раздражает*. Т.к. все тут взрослые люди, и все прекрасно представляют, что на самом деле имелось ввиду. Эфемизм - это замена прямого мата в оскорбительном сообщении. Сообщение при этом менее оскорбительным не становится.

Comment: @VladSpirin у нас в справке явно вписано "Тон ваших сообщений должен быть таким же, как при разговоре с тем, кого вы уважаете и от кого ждёте встречного уважения". Я более чем уверен, что под "уважением" подразумевается "*Почтительное отношение*, основанное на признании чьих-н. достоинств.", а не "братан, ты меня уважаешь?"

Comment: @PashaPash я за цензуру, вот только главное не потерять грань, где она нужна и важна, а где пошел перегиб. Насчет "хрен", возможно вы и правы, к примеру ситуация если женщина обращается, уже как-то не то, неправильно, да или более старшая аудитория. Будет скорее неуважительно звучать. Ну к примеру фраза: "Да фиг его знает...", никакого уж эмоционального и неуважительного окраса не имеет. Так что надо смотреть от ситуации к ситуации.

Comment: @VladSpirin а вы знали, что слово "фиг", это эвфемизм, означающий тоже самое, что и всем известное трёхбуквенное слово? Да и жест, который мы называем "фига", "кукиш" и "дуля" - полный аналог всем известному среднему пальцу, имеющий значение один в один. Лично мне сейчас само слово было противно писать, потому что я прекрасно знаю, что оно означает на самом деле. В общем и целом, Викисловарь вам в помощь.

Comment: @VladSpirin это не цензура. цензура - это "... с целью ограничения либо недопущения распространения идей и сведений, признаваемых властями нежелательными". Мы не ограничиваем распространиение идей и сведений. Мы просто требуем соблюдения правила https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice. По поводу женщин и старшей аудитории - у меня 4 девушки-разработчика в команде. И они тоже бывают на SO. Подумайте о них! :)

Comment: Кстати, «хер» — это всего лишь название буквы из кириллицы, а не то, что ваш испорченный мозг сейчас подумал. Давайте банить за слово «блин», это ведь в определённых контекстах тоже эвфемизм к известному междометию на ту же букву «б» :)

Comment: @andreymal многое зависит от контекста использования. Я знаю, что это название кириллической бкувы. Но ведь мы не о буквах говорили. То же самое касается и "блинов". Всё зависит о контексте. Если речь идёт о вкусном блюде, то проблем нет. А если это слово -паразит, то чего уж там, говорите как есть, по красоте и матом. Одно и тоже, получается.

Comment: @PashaPash вы так все обставили, будто я с вами спорю. Ок, пишу вам по-другому. Я с вами согласен!!!! Слишком много шума из ничего.

Comment: Как пользователь хотелось бы добавить, что существуют такие люди, которые крайне категорично относятся к комментариям или ответам в которых присутствуют слова "Ты". Я один из таких людей, и считаю оскорбительными и невежливыми такие комментарии или ответы.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь а я из таких людей, которые категорически против употребления «вы» (и тем более «Вы») в иных смыслах помимо множественного числа

Comment: @andreymal Я бы с вами поспорил на эту тему, но опасаюсь последствий!

Comment: *"либо мы будем здесь как культурные люди, либо как наши бравые, но – увы! – малообразованные офицеры в казармах. Мак предложил ради разнообразия побыть как культурные люди." (с) Стругацкие, "Обитаемый остров"*  Не стоит лезть в чужой монастырь со своим уставом. Или, если вас так раздражает местный устав - то с волками жить - по-волчьи выть. Да, в FidoNet обращение на "вы" считалось едва ли не оскорблением, но здесь такой практики нет. И слава Богу :) Иной раз, кстати, в раздражении что-то напишешь - и если тебя потом аккуратненько исправят, даже не сделав замечания - становится так стыдно...

Comment: @andreymal Подскажите, вам бы было более удобно, чтобы комментарий удалялся полностью, чем исправлялся?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в первую очередь было бы удобно получать уведомления о том, что я сделал что-то не так, а то вот на Мете ныть приходится. А так согласен с D-side, лучше уж удалять

Comment: @andreymal Дополнил ответ, пояснив почему это не удаление, а правка.

Comment: @andreymal Подскажите, если это было бы не автоматическое сообщение, а после нескольких случаев письмо на почту с несколькими примерами, было бы это удовлетворяющим вас решением?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky по крайней мере это было бы лучше чем сейчас

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь `существуют такие люди, которые крайне категорично относятся к комментариям или ответам в которых присутствуют слова "Ты"` — надо использовать обезличенные предложения, и проблема с обращениями решится сама собой.

Comment: Ура! Наконец-то избавились от метки "важное".

Comment: Что за хрень!!! :D Меня тоже такая фигня раздражает! Это не мат и если это кого-то оскорбляет - то идите в садик в куклы играть. Это крайне важно даже для руководств (дабы они не были слишком скучными) и замена этих слов сильно меняет смысл. И насчет ты/вы: вы когда работаете в команде тоже к друг другу на вы обращаетесь? Где я работал всегда общались на ты, благо и возраст почти одинаковый, ну разве что с начальниками лучше на вы. А программисты на SO - это такое же сообщество как и на работе, поэтому я не вижу смысла кому-то тут "выкать".

Comment: Но по сабжу (если не менять политику), то лучше пусть правят чем удаляют. Ведь комментарии нельзя потом прочитать (да и темы кажется тоже если не сам удалил, хотя их обычно не удаляют, а закрывают) - вот что печалит меня (кстати такая же проблема с темами и на Тостере). Вот бывает пишешь что-то долго, написал здоровый пост, а его взяли и удалили... Может там можно было что-то поправить, но восстановить или посмотреть уже никак нельзя и только вспоминать что там было... Это очень печалит и отбивает желание писать что-либо еще.

Comment: Результат голосования по вопросу печален весьма.

Comment: @edem, а где голосование-то?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь ПРОСТИТЕ(прости) но у ВАС(тебя) видимо чсв зашкаливает если не ЛЮБИТЕ(любишь) когда к ВАМ(тебе) обращаются в единственном числе а не во множественном. ВЫ(ты) не царь ведь ?)))

Comment: @Montreal голоса за/против.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков дожили, теперь культуру общения воспринимают, как "завышенное чсв" *рукалицо*

Comment: @edem, это, конечно, только моё мнение, но культуру общения можно поддерживать, а насаждать нельзя. Если "плохие" слова запретить, то возникнет такое явление как декаданство: нельзя говорить "плохие" слова, а я буду, ведь я бунтарь. Или будут использовать эвфемизмы, потом запретят эвфемизмы и так далее. В конечном счёте, люди говорят то, что хотят сказать.

Comment: @Montreal у бунтарей не завидная судьба, если что)

Comment: А зачем для выражения технической информации "хрен" и "фиг"? А как именно эти слова *помогают* выполнять его основную миссию?

Comment: интересные вопросы обсуждаются ) считаю, что править нужно только ошибки, грамматически и пунктуационные, логические, если автор слишком задумался и написал какой то бред, который с первой бутылки не поймешь

Answer (score 39):

(По заявкам <s>радиослушателей</s> других участников переношу в ответ; может, кто-то минус хочет поставить, а комментарию никак. Непорядок!)

### [Я и сам с этим сталкивался](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36565154#36565154). И довольно давно.

В сущности, в разгаре очередной драмы Николас без предупреждения (ни предварительного, ни постфактум) заменил в моём комментарии `что за чушь :D` на `вы не правы :D`, чем напрочь убил эмоциональную окраску комментария, т. к. то, на что я отвечал, если я верно помню, меня здорово рассмешило. И смайлик стал совершенно неуместным.

Отмечу, правда, что дело было **здесь, на Мете**, а не на самом Stack Overflow на русском. Здесь, в отличие от SO, обсуждение *мнений* это обычное дело. Это важно. Здорово влияет на характер дискуссий.

Я изъявил своё недовольство таким разрешением ситуации Николасу, он [отказался](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36566692#36566692) возвращать как было. Не имея никакого желания устраивать метадраму (в смысла, драму из драмы, не драму на Мете) я удалил комментарий целиком. Привилегии для этого не нужны.

Я не утверждаю, что этот пример сколько-нибудь похож на то, о чём речь в вопросе; но решение, которое мы с Николасом выработали в моём случае, на мой взгляд, отлично работает и для этого. Вот.

---

Почему меня вообще это возмутило?

Моя личная политика (которая по факту упирается в лицензии, но до них не доходит) достаточно простая: пожалуйста, **не приписывайте мне того, чего я не говорил**. Если сообществу не нравится эмоциальная окраска *моего* контента, то оно не имеет морального права её изменять (в частности, смягчать), *оставляя моё авторство*. Это прямое **приписывание мне чужих слов**, что я категорически не приемлю (а очевидных ремарок о том, что сообщение изменено модератором, нет; и к этому я ещё вернусь). **Удаление такого контента вовсе (сообщений целиком) мне видится более приемлемым**. Даже если его в дальнейшем переопубликует кто-то другой в более мягкой форме. Я не буду рад, но спорить из-за этого уже не стану.

Но это не единственный выход, конечно. Ну, то есть, в *комментариях* единственный. А вот в случае с *ответами* я могу пойти на компромисс и сделать ответ общим ([был случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/652735/revisions)), фактически отказавшись от авторства и передав дальнейшую поддержку сообщения сообществу.

Но, на секундочку, я тоже часть сообщества, поэтому всё ещё буду готов вносить в ответ какие-то технические улучшения, если таковые найдутся. Но говоря от лица сообщества, никаких едкостей я себе уже в общем сообщении не позволю.

И я могу быть не согласен с модераторами и считать, что флаги на подобные мелкие едкости полагается *отклонять*, но решение принимают модераторы, а не я.

---

Теоретически я вижу ещё один вариант: если чётко обозначить, что к сообщению применил правку модератор, и выделить изменённый фрагмент, благодаря чему становится сразу видно, какие именно слова из приведённых мои, то всё будет честно и я не буду против.

Как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но насколько мне известно, никакой "особой модераторской разметки" для фрагментов текста на Stack Exchange не существует, а фича эта настолько нишевая, что я бы не рассчитывал на её реализацию.

Comment: Поддерживаю подход "если удалять - то целиком". Проблема с едкостями (или даже едокостями на грани) в том, что, как показал опыт, едкости токсичны. Т.е. или особо едкий участник становится все более едким (и начинает открыто оскорблять), или другие участники (в основном, новички) начинают вести себя так, как "принято", причем каждый старается выделится из серой едкой толпы. К сожалению, единственный способ такое пресечь - удалять по первой тревоге то, что "на грани". Модераторы перестраховываются, т.к. были вполне конкретные переходы за грань, приведшие к годовым банам.

Comment: @PashaPash s/токсичны/заразны?

Comment: Скорее, постепенно накапливающиеся в организме.

Comment: В смысле, "выводятся слишком медленно", и потому делают атмосферу более токсичной со временем, если не предпринимать мер по выведению. Тут я не совсем согласен: сообщество ведь постоянно растёт, а на воспринимаемый уровень токсичности влияет то, какое её количество случайный посетитель может увидеть. Поэтому достаточно слабые едкости не окажут существенного влияния, они будут задавлены "чистым". Вопрос, как определить эту грань "слабости-несущественности". Отчётливо наблюдаю, что грань модераторов (кроме, может, Qwertiy) явно ниже моей. :)

Comment: Да, вот только едкость обычно проявляется в виде реакции на вопросы новичков. И на ответы новичков. Они *чем-то неуловимым* бесят определенных участников - то ли неполнотой, то ли нарушением наших *неопределенных* правил. При этом новички - самые чувствительные к такому. Разработчики и так, в основном, интроверты, многим надо через себя переступить, чтобы вопрос задать. Разобраться в местных правилах. Запостить код не картинкой. А им в ответ начинается всякое.

Comment: В качестве примера - как-то раз, еще во времена когда я модерировал vingrad и msdn, я попытался ответить на вопрос по C# на одном из достаточно популярных русских форумов. Немного опечатался, в тексте, не в коде. Движок форума, внезапно, не дал мне эту опечатку исправить. Местные "опытные" решили что опечатка - это повод устроить стеб в стиле "научись печатать". Никакого "существенного влияния", но форум остался без меня, им же хуже :) Но на SO - мне не нравится терять потенциально полезных участников из-за токсичности отдельных товарищей.

Comment: @D-side одно дело редактирование эмоционально окрашенного "что за чушь", а другое дело вульгарные эвфемизмы. Что касается "что за чушь" => "вы не правы", то я с вами согласен. Такое редактирование на мой взгляд тоже неуместно. А редактирование вульгарных слов, наравне с нецензурными, можно проводить и без согласования с автором сообщения. Более того, я считаю что это даже нужно. :)

Comment: "Моя личная политика (которая по факту упирается в лицензии, но до них не доходит) достаточно простая: пожалуйста, не приписывайте мне того, чего я не говорил." вас так послушать, то и весь функционал "Править" нужно отменить для пользователей, оставив лишь один "Удалить".

Comment: @edem править чужие комментарии нельзя, а последний редактор у вопросов и ответов довольно ярко отображается рядом с автором, поэтому к функциональности сайта в этом ключе у меня нет претензий. А правки, которые "я этого может и не говорил, но точно сказал бы, если б мог" я считаю полезными. Но это исчезающе редкий случай, который сделал бы политику заметно сложнее и непонятнее.

Comment: Я за редактирование (так сказать меньшее из двух зол), ну или лучше вообще не трогать конечно. Но идея с пометкой "исправлено модератором" мне чертовски нравится!!! Даже неплохо бы во всплывающей подсказке показывать оригинальный текст автора.

Comment: @D-side забанили что ли? А то у меня вместо имени аккаунта показывает "userXXXXXX"

Comment: Или это секретная информация?

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard Он сам удалил профиль, из-за некоторых конфликтов в сообществе.

Answer (score 15):

### Разговорщине место в чате, а не в базе знаний

Сильная эмоциональная окраска, это оперирование красноречием, а не фактами.

SO - это огромная база вопросов и ответов, используемая как справочник сотнями тысяч разработчиков. Воспринимайте её как документацию, как википедию, а не как загаражные летние посиделки (или местечковые форумы).

Comment: Я буду рад, если разговорщина будет немного присутствовать и в документации со справочниками :)

Comment: А я вот до сих пор не знаю как быстро комментарии в чат превратить, да и создание чата к вопросу такое себе прозрачное, и таких 90% пользователей

Answer (score 9):

Полностью поддерживаю @andreymal и @D-side, что НЕ надо делать подобные замены.

Дело в том, что Николас настроил какую-то автоматическую штуковину для сбора подобных комментов и активно зачищает всё подряд - судя по всему, что-то правками, что-то просто сносит как оскорбления, после чего Дух ещё и генерирует тревогу на несколько удалённых оскорбительных комментариев (многие участники уже получили уведомления).

На мой взгляд, большинство этих комментариев нейтральные, трогать их не надо.

---

Кажется, всё ещё хуже, чем я думал. Вот последние три удалённые Николасом с использованием тревоги **невежливый или оскорбительный** комментария:

> А десятка минусов за "разплывчатый вопрос" тоже хватит?

Плюсов на комментарии: 2
Вопрос: [Метод шифрования текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/813714/178988)

> Тут вам не фриланс если хотите чтобы вам помогли вы и сами должны показать что стараетесь

Плюсов на комментарии: 4
Вопрос: [Как получить такой эффект при :hover?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/813727/178988)

> А мы как должны по кофейной гуще гадать? Или телепатией? Где код?

Плюсов на комментарии: 7
Вопрос (удалён автором): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/813223/178988

Обращаю внимания, я ничего не подбирал, я просто взял 3 верхних записи [со страницы профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/6):

[image: скриншот тревог]

---

А вот исправленные комментарии, о которых говорят @andreymal и @D-side:

> [image: скриншот комментария 1]
>
> [image: скриншот комментария 2]
>
> [image: скриншот комментария 3]

Comment: А было ли хотя бы какое-то уведомление об этих автозаменах? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, замены не авто, Николас всё делает руками и очень доволен. Робот только подкидывает ему соответствующий "материал".

Comment: Уточняю свою позицию: на мой взгляд, сносить начисто лучше, чем исправлять на более мягкие формулировки. Более развернуто описал в ответе.

Comment: А вот [возьму](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36566645#36566645) и [докажу](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36565169#36565169)! :D Спасибо за поддержание прозрачности происходящего.

Comment: @Qwertiy Большинство этих комментариев нейтральные, трогать их не надо? *Ишь, какой умный! Какие нахрен нейтральные, что за чушь ты несешь, ты в своем уме? Тебе что, религия не позволяет правила почитать перед тем, как на мете отвечать? Или ты читаешь их с закрытыми глазами? С тобой бесполезно иметь дело, ты непробиваемый. Без толку, не знаешь, лучше молчи, кто-то другой даст знать.*. Это краткое содержание комментариев, которые ты предлагаешь оставить :)

Comment: @Qwertiy т.е. да, эмоциональная окраска - это хорошо. Чуть-чуть эмоциональной окраски в каждом сообщении - тоже неплохо. Но только до тех пор, пока это не задевает других людей. Лично мне не нравится общение в таком стиле. Если кому-то нравится - они вправе собираться в собственном community и там друг другу высказывать что угодно. А у нас тут, извините, бинайс.

Comment: @PashaPash согласен с тем что обижать людей не надо, но можно с позиции русского языка всё чисто сказать и тем не менее будет обидно, например предложить погуглить...

Comment: @PashaPash, кого обижает эта фраза: _"А мы как должны по кофейной гуще гадать? Или телепатией? Где код?"_?

Comment: @Qwertiy она не обижает, но вот терпение и доброжелательность из нее *аж прет*. " **Будьте дружелюбными, терпеливыми и доброжелательными.** Не ожидайте от новых участников знания всех правил – это невозможно. Пожалуйста, проявите терпение, пока они их выучат." - где в это все?

Comment: @Qwertiy хочешь донести до новичка, что приведенного в вопросе **недостаточно**, и что код картинкой постят только и***ты - доноси это спокойно. Это "А мы как должны" подразумевает, что отвечающие прямо вот обязаны, должны гадать. Не должны. Никто на них не давит, гадать не требует и KPI по ответам им не ставит. Не хочешь и не умеешь гадать - проходи мимо.

Comment: @PashaPash: С другой стороны, если новички не обязаны думать перед тем как задать вопрос, почему у нас должен срабатывать самостоп перед тем как написать комментарий? Написал плохой вопрос — получи свою долю сарказма.

Comment: @VladD новички обязаны думать, но они вполне могут надумать не то, что надумали старички на мете. Например, многие постят ошибки картинкой, т.к. думают что это *удобнее для отвечающих*. Многие считают, что сообщения об ошибке будет достаточно и без кода Просто потому, что если бы у них хватило знаний, чтобы понять, что это не так - то у них хватило бы знаний чтобы решить проблему самостоятельно, типичный пример - NullReferenceException-вопросы.

Comment: @VladD У новичка выбор - или задать вопрос как сможет, или не задать вообще. Т.е. вы не видите последствия выбора "не задал вопрос (т.к. побоялся местных особо саркастичных товарищей)". У комментатора - или съявзить, или промолчать. *Самостоп тут ни при чем*. Думать про задавшего вопрос можно что угодно. Просто *иногда* нужно подумать и промолчать.

Comment: @PashaPash, а нам точно нужны участники, обижающиеся на фразу про отсутствие телепатов? И так вон с парой странных участников мучаемся, хотим ещё развести? Адекватные люди на адекватные фразы адекватно реагируют, вообще-то.

Comment: А ещё, @PashaPash, ты так и не сказал, что оскорбительного в моём тебе комментарии (под этим ответом), который удалил Николас.

Comment: @Qwertiy я сказал что это не мое дело - я на тот комментарий флаг не ставил, никак его не оценивал. Разбирайтесь сами.

Comment: @Qwertiy насчет телепатов - в той фразе проблема не в слове телепатов, а в общем тоне. Задавший вопрос этому конкретному комментатору *ничего не должен*. Комментатор ему тоже ничего не должен. У нас тут все добровольно. Не хочешь быть дружелюбным, терпеливым и доброжелательным - никто не заставляет, просто иди мимо. Даже думать не надо: хочешь кода - поставь тревогу, в которой вписано нейтральное пожелание

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну смотрите, вы задали вопрос. В ответ вам летит сообщение про телепатию. Человек нормальный, но признавать какую-то вещь, которая была сказана с наездом, иногда с какой-то обидной экспрессивной оценкой, разумеется человек не будет - психология(гордость,самоуважение). Нелегко сказать: "Мой вопрос чепуха, признаю, дайте время, сейчас исправлю". Для того, чтобы признать ошибку и не ответить негативом на негатив, нужно уметь себя контролировать. А негатив на то и негатив, что человек не хочет его получать. Это сообщение(ваше) несет в себе смысл унижения человека, хотите вы этого или нет.

Answer (score 5):

Согласен с авторами вопроса и ответами @andreymal , @D-side и @Qwertiy.

В сообщениях есть смысл, и этот смысл не только техническая информация но и эмоциональная и другая. Менять смысл сообщения не нужно. С точки зрения перспектив развития сайта как бы это можно делать, так как эта эмоциональная составляющая как бы не значима по сравнению с технической, но на самом деле это не так. Дело в том, что если в моменте Здесь и Сейчас, запороть автору общение и настроение, то стратегически и потом возможно этот автор уже не напишет нужные сообщения на сайт и не ответит где мог бы ответить. Кроме того задача сайта это не только база ответов но и текущие ответы конкретным пользователям. Не было бы конкретных текущих вопросов и ответов не было бы и базы.

Кроме того что сказано авторами которых я указал вверху своего сообщения, я считаю неправильным удалять истории, приветы и благодарности, кроме случаев где это реально не в тему. Так как эти моменты помогают стать людям работающих на сайте, спрашивающих тут и отвечающих более счастливыми, радостными, получить удовлетворение.

Разумеется оскорбления, провокаторские сообщения, мат удалять необходимо.

Кроме того при желании эту информацию можно удалять например через месяц после публикации вопросов и ответов, так как эмоциональная составляющая уже отработает и станет неактуальной участникам общения.

Comment: Эмоциональная окраска не устаревает.

Comment: @Qwertiy "Эмоциональная окраска" моих сообщений помогла стать более счастливыми и радостными миллионам людей. Не говоря уже о том, скольким она помогла получить удовлетворение. И скольким еще поможет.

Comment: @Igor, тебе уже написали сообщение на эту тему. При том, что я пару раз отклонял автоматическую тревогу про несколько оскорбительных комментариев, когда они были кучкой под одним сообщением потёрты. Впрочем, часть из них действительно была где-то на грани и удалена скорее правильно, чем неправильно (но не все).

Comment: @Qwertiy "Хотел я с этими модераторами схлестнуться, но поскольку у меня была высокая температура, 39 и 8, то я с ними спорить не стал. Я только им сказал: - Вот погоди, медицинская трубка, ..."

Comment: Вульгарная речь не очень далеко от нецензурной. Я с вами согласен насчёт излишнего желания удалять "приветы, предыстории и благодарности" - сам грешу их написанием. А вот упомянуты ТС-ом слова - уж простите... Это вульгарные слова, которым тут не место. Впрочем, я свою точку зрения изложил в ответе.

Comment: @Qwertiy сама окраска не устаревает, я согласен, просто для участников уже вопрос завершается, я это имел ввиду.

Answer (score 4):

Миссия Stack Overflow — *общими силами* создать *библиотеку* подробных ответов на все прикладные вопросы *по программированию*.

#### Ключевая вода или Кока–кола?

Крайне здорово выпить Кока-колы по дороге на работу в полуденный зной, но не во время участия в марафоне. Большинство людей попадают на сайт, когда ищут решение технической задачи, то есть по работе, а не для того, чтобы «тусануть».

В Кока–коле нет ничего плохого, но для марафона лучше взять ключевой воды.

#### Атмосфера знания

Человеку крайне важно окружение, в котором он взаимодействует. Заходя в спортзал, офис, университет, музей, церковь или пивной бар мы ведем себя по–разному. Каждый понимает, что бегать можно в зале, но не во время лекции, можно услышать нецензурную лексику баре и, иногда, в офисе, но не в музее или церкви. Все эти заведения как институты имеют свои особенности и ограничения в контексте допустимого. И как бы нам не хотелось, сидя в баре мы никогда не сможем освоить столько же знаний, как в библиотеке. Нам нужно спокойствие и концентрация.

Stack Overflow — это, по определению, место, где происходит обмен и накопление знаний в максимально концентрированном виде. Чтобы этого достичь необходимо поддерживать «академическую» атмосферу, с той разницей, что мы все на равных: каждый из нас и ученик и учитель одновременно (сегодня пошутите вы, завтра — над вами, после завтра на сайте никого не останется).

#### Общественный договор: взаимное общечеловеческое уважение

В двух словах, наш [общественный договор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80) сводится к тому, что опытные участники сайта уважительно относятся к новичкам и не выходят за рамки профессионального академического взаимодействия (не разрушают «атмосферу знаний»), а взамен система дает им [куда более «властные» инструменты модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6963/6): голоса против, тревоги, закрытие и удаление вопросов. То есть мы уважаем людей как таковых (не пишем колкости) безотносительно качества их вопросов, но строго требуем выполнять [созданные нами правила](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), иначе мы блокируем их дальнейшее взаимодействие, вплоть до полного запрета публикации чего–либо на сайте.

[Любые неуважительные комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349/) — это нарушение этого договора.

#### Чем больше ешь, тем больше хочется

Когда–то каждый из нас остановился у чистого горного озера. Вот кто–то решил «подсластить» воду. Все одобрили. Потом следующий подсластил. Никто не заметил. Кроме одного, кому показалось мало и раз уж никто «не против», то почему бы не сделать совсем хорошо? Потом еще и еще. В какой–то момент все поняли, что вода уже слишком сладка, чтобы пить, и кто–то виноват — не известно.

С первого дня существования сайта, благодаря помощи самых влюбленных в сообщество участников, мы старались поддерживать атмосферу знания. Каждый, кто когда–то присоединился, присоединился к сайту, где «не место разговорщине». Потому что сайту доверяют люди и не бояться задавать вопросы, потому что в сообществе много увлеченных программированием знатоков и энтузиастов, таких же как и вы. Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы к нам и дальше присоединялись такие замечательные люди как вы, чтобы с каждым днем все больше и больше людей не боялись задавать профессиональные вопросы в Интернете. Для этого надо сохранить то, почему каждый из нас решил остановиться у этого горного озера.

---

**Дополнение**

#### Слова с корнем «хрен»

Сейчас я вижу на сайте 778 комментариев со словом «хрен» (`where lower(Text) LIKE N'%хрен%'`) из них ужалены только 95. Многие удаления — это перенос в чат. Случайно выбранные из удаленных

- > Доктор очень зол, что за хрень с чатом??
- > я конечно благодарен, но я вообще не понимаю нахрена вы превращаете замечательный язык программирования в нечитаемую кашу в которой хрен разберёшься, это убого, ломает мозг, глаза и всё удовольствие от программирования. но зато можно выпендриваться, не спорю
- > тебе что делать нехрена?

Очень много не удаленных комментариев с корнем «хрен», которые содержат слово «хрень» в значении «штуковина». Их можно было бы заменить на конкретное название самой «штуковины», что невероятно повысило бы информативность сообщений.

#### «Фиг»

Слова с корнем «фиг» посчитать не так просто: конфигурация, фигура, нафига — все попадают под шаблон. Взглянем по отдельности на несколько.

- Нафига: 15 удаленных из 216. Все удаления — это перенос в чат или удаление автором комментария. Значение одно — «зачем»/«почему».
- Фигу: всего 6, удалено о. Цитирую:

  - > Если вы лезете в книгу, а видите фигу - это не моя проблема.
  - > Микрософт фигу показывает, к сожалению.
  - > Тогда пример в студию, а то я только фигу увидел у них на сайте
  - > эмпирически. Впрочем, еще раз повторю - в 146% случаев всем по фигу на них. В дипломе есть куда более интересные для комиссии аспекты
- Пофигу: всего 151, удалено 7. Опять же, удаления это перенос или автором. Значение — «безразлично».

#### Выводы

Таким образом, в некоторых случаях, комментарии со словом «хрен» действительно надо удалять, они оскорбительные. В других случаях комментарии надо подправить для повышения читаемости комментариев. Что было и сделано в вашем случае. «Фиг», как оказалось, вообще особо никто не трогал, хотя на мой взгляд, написав «безразлично» или «не имеет значения» вместо «нафиг», автор бы ничуть не изменил эмоциональную окраску.

#### Почему стоит вносить такие правки

Такими правками мы повышаем информативность комментария, что упрощает понимание текста читателю. Когда вы называете вещи своими именами, читателю не надо останавливаться и идти читать все предыдущие комментарии, вопрос и ответ еще раз, чтобы понять какой именно «хреновине» «пофиг» и в чем это «пофиг» выражается. Заметьте, «исходный массив не изменится» звучит понятней, чем «хреновине пофиг».

Повторюсь, миссия Stack Overflow, то есть то, зачем сайт был запущен, зачем каждый день сотрудники компании приходят на работу, почему многие из участников заходят на сайт — *общими силами* создать *библиотеку* подробных ответов на все прикладные вопросы *по программированию*. Пожалуйста, старайтесь повышать информативность ваших сообщений, в том числе и комментариев самостоятельно и не ругайтесь, если кто–то хочет помочь улучшить ваш комментарий. Чем информативнее ваши сообщения, тем их быстрее прочитать и проще понять.

---

В комментариях была задета тема эвфемизмов. Крайне интересная мысль высказывалась на этот счёт в общем в книге «Пиши, сокращай» (авторы Максим Ильяхов, Людмила Сарычева):

> Эвфемизмы не только неинформативные, но и малодушные. Они
>   показывают неуважение к собеседнику, трусость и нарциссизм
>   одновременно: человек как бы хочет вас оскорбить, но не хочет
>   выглядеть при этом плохо в чужих глазах. Поэтому он вас оскорбит
>   изящно, чтобы другие подумали: «Какой умница!»

Comment: «Чтобы этого достичь необходимо поддерживать «академическую» атмосферу» — мне осталось непонятно, почему это является обязательным условием. И так же осталось непонятно, какое отношение «хрен» да «фиг» имеют к уважению или его отсутствию.

Comment: @andreymal Возможно, указанные вами слова не так страшны. Но это только начало. Далее, расширив рамки допустимого, уже не так страшно будет добавить и что–то более грубое. На мой взгляд, это не верная дорога и ее не стоит начинать. Заметьте, в обычном ВУЗе скажут скорее «ты не получишь зачет, так как не знаешь», но не «хрен тебе, а не зачет, нифига не выучил опять». На работе скажут «бонусов не будет, ты не выполнил поставленных задач в срок», но не «нафига тебе бонусы платить, ты хреново работал». В одном случае объясняют что и как, во втором — осуждают, высмеивают. Это огромная разница.

Comment: Согласитесь, что между недопустимостью неуважительных комментариев и правкой сообщений без уведомлений разница довольно большая. Давайте уважать право участников писать сообщения так, как им этого хочется. А если оно нарушает правила сообщества - удалять, наказывать или менять правила.

Comment: RuSO рискует превратиться в пиратский перевод SO, гнусавым голосом Володарского и заменой оригинальных оборотов на "осел (догадайтесь, какая анатомическая подробность в оригинале)" и "обожемой".

Comment: _"Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы к нам и дальше присоединялись"_ - а чтобы не разбежались присоединившиеся, не хочется?

Comment: @gbg Пожалуйста, поясните, про что вы говорите? Почему отсутствие грубости перевод сайт в перевод SOen?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky аналогия состоит в том, что советские переводчики, в виду природной интеллигентности, сильно смягчали выражения в своих работах.

Comment: А по теме же я скажу, что вместо увлеченных своей работой профессионалов в оставите в сообществе пидагогов, которые любят веселую циферку возле своей аватарки, а по предмету плавают +-два лаптя, изобретая в C++ конструктор для int "с целью упрощения изложения"

Comment: Невидимые и необсуждаемые правки приносят больше вреда чем «неуважительные» комментарии и не имеют никакого воспитательного эффекта. Удаление комментариев с предупреждением пользователя видится более открытым и правильным решением.

Comment: @gbg Обновил ответ. По переводчикам и цензуре: для моего обывательского понимания этого понятия, цензура возможна лишь в открытом информационном пространстве, где действует регулятор, регулирующий правила. Наш сайт не такая система. Он бы создан с определенной целью и с заданными с начала правилами. Если кто–то хочет помочь в достижении цели — создании свободной базы знаний — с установленными базовыми правилами, он(а) присоединяется к проекту и своим добродетелем помогает коллегам.

Comment: Прийти на сайт и использовать пусть допустимые слова в каких–то компаниях, но не допустимые на Stack Overflow исходя из миссии, идеологии и принятых подходах проекта, а потом говорить о несправедливости и цензуре — не верно. Это как прийти в бар с живой музыкой, сесть у сцены и ругаться на администраторов, что шумно или, с обратной стороны, прийти в библиотеку университета и сетовать, что запрещено кричать и выражаться как вздумается. У каждого из этих мест есть свое назначение, свои случаи использования.

Answer (score -3):

> Нечего делать из сайта какую-то унылую фигню, в которой не место
>   разговорщине — она никак не мешает выполнять сайту его основную
>   задачу.

**Пьяный** в стельку грузчик тоже **может исправно выполнять свою основную функцию**, только вот наймут ли его, а то мало ли, ещё диван уронит, кто его знает... **Лучше нанять трезвого**, пожалуй.

Так что "никак не мешает" это спорное утверждение.

Метка "важное", зачем, что тут важного то?..

Comment: Т. е. удаление всего подряд - это не важно?

Comment: @Qwertiy удаление таких словечек, а не всего подряд. Да, здесь ничего важного не вижу. Обычная операция по приведению текста к читабельному виду.

Answer (score -7):

Всем привет. Не смог пройти мимо...
Лично я категорически не согласен с автором, и поддерживаю Николаса и Павла.

@VladSpirin и @andreymal а вы знали, что слово "фиг", это вульгарный эвфемизм, означающий тоже самое, что и всем известное трёхбуквенное слово, куда многие посылают друг друга?.. Да и сам жест, который мы называем "фига", "кукиш" и "дуля" - полный аналог всем известному среднему пальцу, имеющий значение один в один. Лично мне сейчас само слово было противно писать, потому что я прекрасно знаю, что оно означает на самом деле. Если не верите, то Викисловарь вам в помощь, там есть замечательная статья ["фиг"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Тоже самое касается первого упомянутого вами слова. Опять же, добро пожаловать в Викисловарь, а именно к этому [подзаголовку](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_2). Прочитайте, пожалуйста, о значении этих эвфемизмов и их происхождении.

Итог: упоминаемые вами слова являются вульгарными эвфемизмами, которым не место на ruSO. Им вообще не место в какой-либо речи. Я понимаю, что соблюдать культуру речи, возможно, сложно для вас ввиду вашего менталитета, общества, которое вас окружает или, как вариант, небольшого словарного запаса... Но проявите, пожалуйста, уважением к своим коллегам, которым такая речь неприятна.

Искренне надеюсь на ваше понимание.
С уважением, Юрий.

P.S.: вот вам ещё ссылочка на википедию, где описано происхождение слова "фиг" - [кукиш: происхождение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%88#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%C2%AB%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%88%C2%BB,_%C2%AB%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%88%C2%BB,_%C2%AB%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%C2%BB,_%C2%AB%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%C2%BB,_%C2%AB%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%C2%BB).

Comment: Эвфемизмы на то и эвфемизмы, что их можно упротреблять (последние пять букв этого слова вас тоже раздражают?) там, где исходные выражения употреблять нельзя.

Comment: @andreymal простите, _PPS_ это была моя ошибка. :) В определении имелось ввиду другое, я с запятыми не сразу разобрался. Однако, я считаю, что некоторые эвфемизмы приобретают негативный оттенок вульгарных слов, или сами являются вульгарными. Что касается слова, простите, "фиг", то хоть оно и считается в русском языке эвфемизмом, но само слово происходит от вульгарного выражения. Не просто означает вульгарный жест, но и происходит от вульгарного выражения. Для этого я вам и ссылки дал. :)

Comment: И да, почему меня должны раздражать последние 5 букв слова "эвфемизм", если он происходит от древнегреческого, означающее "благоречие"? Я что-то не пойму. :)

Comment: @andreymal эвфемизмы заменяют мат, но не изменяют суть высказывания. Их употребляют в ситуации, когда нужно показать/выразить оскорбление, но нельзя прямо употреблять мат. Что отправить отправить человека "на хрен", что на более короткий вариант - человек все равно отправлен туда же, и ему от этого не менее обидно. У нас правила требуют *уважительного отношения*. А не использования "нематных слов". Проблема не в словах, проблема в отсутствии уважения. крестныйотец.jpg

Comment: @PashaPash я никого никуда не посылаю, а всё остальное отсутствием уважения не является

Comment: @andreymal я это прекрасно понимаю :) просто достаточно тяжело определить грань между "не посылаю" и "послал" в общему случае. Не применительно к вашим сообщениям, а в целом для всех тревог на комментариях.

Comment: @andreymal т.е. завтра кто-нибудь возьмет и пошлет кого-нибудь на х**н. И в качестве оправдания - приведет ссылку на мету. Мол, это не мат, ему можно, а мне нет, правила для всех одинаковы, за что меня? Будет драма.

Comment: @PashaPash так-то можно и абсолютно культурными литературными словами умудриться оскорбить) Для подобных случаев нужен какой-то другой критерий бинайса

Comment: @andreymal да, можно, и еще как (по слухам, на rus.stackexchange.com именно так и оскорбляют, не подкопаешься). критерий бинайса - уважительный тон, терпимость к новичкам, никакой агрессии. "А хрен знает как запускать" в сторону участника с 155 баллами - агрессии нет, но я бы не сказал что это "уважительный тон по отношению к новичку".  Хотя в результате новичок оказался доволен.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, постоянное навязывание бинайса вызывает раздражение.

Comment: @intro94, третий вариант по твоей ссылке: _"предик., эвф., прост., экспр., отрицательная частица не; употребляется для выражения сомнения в осуществимости либо отрицания действия, выраженного следующим за ней глаголом, обычно в будущем времени или в условном наклонении"_ - именно в этом значении он был употреблён в комментарии. А некий орган называют, наверное, тысячей разных слов, абсолютно никак с ним не связанных, так что так себе аргумент.

Comment: @Qwertiy здесь можно вспомнить первый коммент в [этом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6793))

Comment: @andreymal, вот-вот))))

Comment: *"А вот как быть с выражением «фиг тебе»? Во-первых, фигу, она же дуля, она же кукиш, надлежало самым решительным образом отмежевать от плода фигового дерева, дабы не подумал Таками, что слова «фиг тебе» означают «подношу тебе в подарок спелую, сладкую фигу». А во-вторых, фига, она же дуля, она же кукиш, означает для японца нечто иное, нежели для европейца или, по крайней мере, для русского. Этой несложной фигурой из трех пальцев в Японии когда-то пользовались уличные дамы, выражая готовность обслужить клиента…" (с) Стругацкие, "Хромая судьба"*

Comment: @Harry я немного не понимаю, к чему вы ведёте? У Стругацких есть одна неточность - фига, она же инжир, в японском языке записывается как **イチジク**, и читается как **Ichijiku**, и не имеет ничего общего с обсуждаемым эвфимизмом, берущем своё начало в европейских язках. А что касается кукиша, то да - сам кукиш, в Китае, Корее и Японии имеет крайне неприличное значение и выступает как фаллический символ. Но смысл этого жеста такой же и для европейца - не все об знают, просто, и считают его безобидным. :)

Comment: Домыслы. Рассматриваемые слова давно и прочно вошли в язык без привязки к обозначению полового органа. От них и производные слова пошли - "хрень" или "фигня" в значении "чепуха" уж точно никак к половой теме не относится. Нужно намеренно закрывать глаза, чтобы это не видеть.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight почему люди интересуются историей мира, но не интересуются происхождением (читайте - историей) слов? Не важно, к чему их применяют, важно то, что они означают в своей сути, этимология слова. И это не домыслы. Это реальное происхождение. Информация приведённая мной основывается не на голой теории и самописных сайтах, а на реальных пруфах.

Comment: Главным образом потому, что происхождение слов трудно установить достоверно. История не сохраняет устную речь, а письменность была доступна только ограниченной части общества в течение долгого времени. Впрочем, это не имеет никакого значения. Нормы языка строятся на текущей ситуации, а не на этимологии.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если так узко мыслить... Нормы морали могут падать, но кто сказал что это хорошо? Да и если судить по-вашему, то в **литературной** и **культурной** речи, такие слова не используются. Вопрос - почему? Ответ очевиден.

Comment: А что такое "литературная речь"? Это понятие абсолютно размытое и неопределенное. Есть разные языковые стили, в одних просторечия недопустимы, в других - являются нормой. Если нет никаких аргументов, кроме абстрактных фраз и обвинений в низкой культурности, обсуждение не имеет смысла.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ага, учитывая что классики русской литературы употребляли и "хрен"  "хрен с горы" (который, кстати куда менее обиден чем "старый хрыч") и "сукин сын", потому как эти слова эмоционально орашены но не являются непечатными руательствами. Кстати , те кто говорят что это не цензура, приписывают слову куда более узких смысл. Цензор  - это человек который следит за соблюдением стандарта в тексте (норм), цензура - это его занятие. Нормы дожны быть опубликованной вещью и для печати таковые существуют. А про "употреблять" вспомнился один бот, который заменял это слово на "употричёрт".

Answer (score -11):

Очевидно, что тут собралось интеллигентное общество, а вопросы и ответы содержащие разговорщину сразу теряют свою ценность.

Подобными правками ясно дают понять, что Вам тут не рады и Вам не стоит больше задавать вопросы и отвечать на них.

Comment: Прочитал первое предложение - поставил плюс. Дочитал второе - поменял на минус.

Comment: Если б мне были не рады, я бы не набрал шесть тыщ рейтинга :)

Comment: Подскажите, вы «за» или «против» и, самое главное, почему? Правки были нацелены на улучшение понимания комментария читающим. Подскажите, почему улучшение читабельности комментария является признаком того, что автору комментария не рады на сайте?

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky я против правок. Они никак не повышают читаемость. И часто коверкают смысл того, что изначально хотел сказать автор. Такое улучшение читабельности - это не более чем снобизм.

Comment: @РашенБеар Вы говорите «часто». Чтобы я понял, о чем именно вы говорите, пожалуйста, приведите конкретные цифры и примеры, когда правка «искаверкала» смысл.

Comment: @AK, а если ещё комментарий прочитать?

Comment: У меня на этом ответе детектор сарказма зашкалил; не сломался, не?