# Как удалить все свои комментарии?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, комментарии

Я случайно зашёл в один из старых вопросов, и заметил что мой комментарий был отредактирован модератором, так что смысл сообщения был изменён. При этом я не получал никаких уведомлений. Возможно что есть другие комментарии, текст которых был заменён.

Я не хочу, чтобы другие люди писали комментарии от моего имени. Т.к. я не могу предотвратить изменение моих комментариев другими людьми, я решил удалить все свои комментарии. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/178988

Comment: Лично я, если бы захотел, написал бы скрипт, который через какой-нибудь SEDE отслеживает изменённые комментарии и удаляет только изменённые

Comment: @Suvitruf, изменение "е" на "ё" - это троллинг такой?

Comment: @Abyx нет. Везде заменяю, где вижу. Могу конкретно ваши сообщения больше не трогать, если хотите.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica думаю, что модераторские правки не для того нужны, чтобы править орфографию.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я делаю это как обычный участник. При чём тут модераторские правки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Заводим приложение на stackapps: пишем там вопрос (см. https://stackapps.com/a/4574/65115) , в настройках приложения в OAuth Domain пишем stackexchange.com, жмем галочки Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri.

Получаем wite_access токен на https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=12345&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success

Получаем пачку комментариев

```
$ curl -Ss --output - 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/comments?site=ru.stackoverflow&access_token=abc&key=def' | gunzip | jq .items[].comment_id
```

Пробуем удалить один комментарий

```
$ curl -d 'site=ru.stackoverflow&access_token=abc&key=def' -Ss 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/1785273/delete' | gunzip
```

Удаляем пачку

```
SO_ARGS="site=ru.stackoverflow&access_token=$APP_TOKEN&key=$APP_KEY"
while true; do
  for ID in $(curl -Ss --output - "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/comments?$SO_ARGS" | gunzip | jq .items[].comment_id); do
    sleep 1
    curl -d "$SO_ARGS" -Ss "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/$ID/delete" | gunzip
    echo
  done
done
```

Вывод:

```
{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":10000,"quota_remaining":9886}
{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":10000,"quota_remaining":9885}
{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":10000,"quota_remaining":9884}
{"error_id":407,"error_message":"You cannot perform this action for another 1 second","error_name":"write_failed"}
{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":10000,"quota_remaining":9882}
{"error_id":407,"error_message":"Сегодня вы уже удалили свои комментарии к 20 сообщениям, дальнейшее удаление заблокировано","error_name":"write_failed"}
{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":10000,"quota_remaining":9880}
{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":10000,"quota_remaining":9879}
...
```

К сожалению можно удалять только по одной в секунду.
Иногда оно говорит про квоту в 20 сообщений, но всё равно удаляет.

---

**Upd:** видимо там квота в 20 удалений на бэкэнд, итого удалось удалить порядка сотни комментариев.

Answer (score 2):

Одной такой кнопки нет. Как минимум, в профиле есть список [всех ваших комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177684/abyx?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Из того, что знаю, есть [API на удаление комментария](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-comment).

В SEDE можно получить [все свои комментарии](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1148966/).

Думаю, можно потом поудалять всё скриптом.

Comment: Там квота на 20 удалений, её можно как-то обойти?