# Автотревога на массовое удаление комментариев

Tags: поддержка, тревоги, инструменты-модератора

Когда участник [пытается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9768/178988) массово удалять свои комментарии, срабатывает автоматическая тревога о вандализме.

Однако, в интерфейсе модераторов кнопки для восстановления комментариев, удалённых немодераторами нет (хотя в принципе такое восстановление возможно, если ничего не поменялось). Мне это видится как некое противоречие.

Comment: Имхо, кто угодно вправе удалять свои комментарии, хоть все сразу. Поэтому кнопка для восстановления не нужна, и тревога тоже не нужна.

Comment: @NickVolynkin эта тревога, в случае как и с массовым удалением своих постов, на тот случай, если человека взломали.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а ещё кто угодно может снимать галочки в ответах на свои вопросы. Но за массовое снятие можно [получить бан](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302850/339911).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнопки для восстановления есть, просто они в профиле участника, являющегося автором комментария.