# Удаление комментариев

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, удаление-комментариев

Кто-то регулярно удаляет мои комментарии. Вопрос: Почему?

Comment: Проверка честности модераторов?

Comment: @avp, скорее чтобы понять что является причиной - удаляют же и не объсняют.

Comment: А как надо было объяснять удаление комментария? Дополнительным же комментарием? Личных сообщений тут не предусмотрено. Кроме крайних случаев общения с модераторами, но из-за удалённого комментария вам точно никто не будет писать по модераторскому каналу с объяснением причины.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну например ссылкой на какое-то правило сайта.

Comment: Это могло быть оправдано, будь вы новичок. Но вы же больше трёх лет на сайте.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, не оправдано если модератор не может объяснить причину, и на свое усмотрение может превышать правила сайта.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru какие правила запрещают модератору удалять комментарии?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а следует ли модератор каким-либо правилам сайта?

Comment: Почему он может не следовать правилам сайта?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вот и я думаю, а они есть?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Они [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct). А кто им не следует?

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо.

Comment: Удаление комментариев - это полбеды. Тут их могут изменить без вашего ведома: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9768/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, наверное такое поведение [допустимо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/281034), но каковы границы этого? Нет уведомлений - это очень плохо.

Answer (score 4):

Комментарии недолговечны. Если сообщение было изменено, то комментарий может быть удалён модератором или даже любым участником автоматически по тревоге "Он более не нужен или устарел" [при наличии определённых слов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5899/176217). Это абсолютно нормально и должно быть ожидаемым. Не стоит удивляться пропавшим комментариям.

Comment: Удивляться не стоит, но сответсвующее изменение отношения к сайту вызывает

Comment: @avp вызывает изменение отношения к комментариям, а не к сайту.

Comment: У кого как. Подозреваю, что у обиженных на удаление их комментариев меняется как раз отношение к сайту (точнее к его участникам)

Comment: @avp у обиженных на %что-угодно% меняется отношение