# Обсуждение автора сообщения, а не самого сообщения

Tags: обсуждение, правила, этикет

Приемлемо ли публиковать в комментариях или сообщениях критику в адрес автора сообщения, ставящую под сомнение его умственные способности? Например:

- Вы вообще думали самостоятельно над задачей?
- Кажется, автор просто не способен программировать.
- Это не ваш код, вы его откуда-то стащили и выдаёте за свой.

И тому подобное.

Я всегда считал, что на ruSO не место подобным суждениям. Обсуждать и оценивать так или иначе надо код/алгоритм, а не автора, который его публикует. Это относится как к вопросам так и к ответам.

Как нужно поступать, если подобные публикации появляются на сайте? Почему именно так?

Comment: неприемлемо. И мне кажется уже было обсуждение про личность автора при оценке вопроса. Фактически, данные комментарии нарушают CoC, поэтому их можно флагать.

Comment: @Grundy вот тут уже интереснее. Допустим, модератор отклоняет тревогу, что дальше делать будем?

Comment: Если не согласен с решением модератора можешь воспользоваться формой обратной связи например :) Либо поставить еще один флаг, его может обработать другой модератор

Comment: Третий пример больше похож на просто констатацию факта (особенно если он подкреплён пруфом), и, подозреваю, против «слишком хитрых» пользователей он может быть уместен

Comment: Нельзя (кстати 1 и 3 по мне ок, хотя подкопаться можно), а все равно будут. Можете флагать. Но раз так делают высокореповое участники, то вряд ли флаги сильно подействуют.

Comment: согласен с оратором выше, 1 и 3 не является обсуждением автора. Я часто спрашиваю, что автор сделал сам, чтобы решить свою проблему - не вижу тут никаких оскорблений.

Comment: В 1 формулировка неудачная выбрана, переписать как-то наподобие «Какие попытки решить задачу вы уже предпринимали?» — и будет ок

Comment: Все 3 сообщения довольно токсичны\агрессивны. Флагать их и все.

Comment: *Это не ваш код, вы его откуда-то стащили и выдаёте за свой* - это как раз и есть обсуждение кода (его происхождения) :)

Comment: Пример про код это обсуждение принадлежности кода — допустимо.

Comment: Related: [Should any Meta post that calls out a user by name be deleted, not just downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289909/137096)

Comment: @Harry обсуждение "чей код" имеет хоть какой-то смысл, только если автор утверждает, что код именно его, и авторство кода имеет хоть какое-то отношение к сути вопроса. В случае соревнований, например. А в случае домашки - это просто оффтоп, и на такое всегда можно ответить "ну да, не мой, взял код из методички, пытаюсь доработать"  :)

Comment: Вообще это все похоже на попытку усидеть на двух стульях. С одной стороны, вроде как требуется убрать из вопроса все лишнее (приветы, лирические отступления, и денежную компенсацию - зарплату, которую автор вопроса получит, за то, что скопипастит решение себе в проект). С другой стороны - очень хочется чтобы в вопросе было "я честно сам пытаюсь решать, мамой клянусь!". Не хотите решать домашки - не решайте домашки. Минусуйте и идите дальше - бот приберет через неделю. То, что в комментариях к очередной домашке будет "чей код?" вообще никак не остановит следующего студента. Пустая трата сил.

Comment: @PashaPash: заметный код в ответы без ссылки на источник не хорошо копировать, поэтому вполне уместно попросить добавить ссылку на первоисточник. Мне попадались ответы с моим кодом, что нормально, если есть указание на автора в виде ссылки — "Stealing is the Highest Form of Flattery"

Answer (score 13):

**Во-первых**, существуют [Нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), где не просто сероватым по белому прописано: `Никаких резких замечаний или враждебно настроенных фраз`, но и приведено 4 примера *недружелюбных* и *дружелюбных* фраз.

1. Самая первая фраза, предложенная ТС: `Вы вообще думали самостоятельно над задачей?`, - очень похожа на первую недружелюбную фразу руководства★: `Это гуглится за пять секунд`. То есть это автоматом недопустимо.

> Важно, что в комментариях (**не** в ответе) все же можно попытаться подтолкнуть вопрошающего словами типа: `Попробуйте подумать в направлении...`, `Вы, возможно, не подумали о / забыли о / не учли то, что` и т.п.

2. Вторая фраза, на мой взгляд, даже обсуждению не подлежит: неуважение - раз, завуалированное оскорбление - два, **совершенно** не относится к вопросу - три.
3. Третья фраза также к вопросу не относится совершенно, *однако* если ее трансформировать в вежливое `Являетесь ли вы автором этого кода? Если вы взяли его или некую его часть со стороннего ресурса, возможно, вы можете задать вопрос автору кода прямо на [том-то сайте]`, то эта фраза становится не только вежливой, но и **полезной**. А вот изначальную фразу можно, по-моему, спокойно флагать.

**Во-вторых**, из тех же норм: `Никаких переходов на личности или личных выпадов`. Кратко и понятно. `Не используйте слова, связанные с человеческими качествами` - сразу в *бан* уходят слова "не умеет программировать".

**В-третьих**, бездоказательное "Это не ваш код" тянет на [*клевету*](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/8a73d26dba7976d6c43cc94aa1515368fef256f0/).

**Еще цитаты**:

> **Никакой травли.**
>
> Мы не приемлем высказывания, которые могут обидеть человека

> **Никакого преследования.**
>
> В том числе, но не ограничиваясь: <...> прямые и **завуалированные** угрозы, <...> а также **постоянное неконструктивное встревание в дискуссии**.

### Итог: это недопустимо.

P.S. Увы, часто новички задают одни и те же, одни и те же вопросы изо дня в день, не пытаясь не то что нагуглить, но даже поискать на самом SO похожие вопросы. Здесь многие злятся, и отсюда, видимо, и растут ноги у подобных фраз. К новичкам здесь тоже много вопросов, однако тема сейчас не об этом. Вследствие этого считаю правильным флагать подобные комментарии, а их авторам вместо оскорблений/неуважения либо пропускать легкие (на их взгляд глупые) вопросы, чтобы дать возможность ответить другим пользователям (возможно, более "изсебятрудновыводимым":) или менее профессиональных, которые пока не могут отвечать на сложные вопросы), либо пойти на нашу любимую Мету и обсудить поведение кого угодно здесь: спокойно, с толком и вежливыми диалогами.

★ Руководства не в смысле начальства, а в смысле guide, manual

Comment: "бездоказательное "Это не ваш код" тянет на клевету" - не тянет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ссылка на УК РФ была, конечно, шуткой, однако клевета, насколько я знаю, - это ложное обычно бездоказательное обвинение.

Comment: не ложное, а заведомо ложное. Это существенная разница.

Comment: "бездоказательное "Это не ваш код" тянет на клевету." - *"Сударь, Вы рассуждаете как сутяга." Сесил Форестер "Мичман Хорнблауэр"*

Comment: @Igor [А судьи кто?](https://www.literaturus.ru/2015/08/monolog-chackogo-griboedov-chitat-tekst.html)

Answer (score 7):

Переход на личности недопустим, однако, в 2 из 3 примерах я его не вижу.

Далее выражаю своё личное мнение.

> Вы вообще думали самостоятельно над задачей?

Допустимо. Здесь акцент не на личности, а на действии - сначала подумать над задачей, потом что-то сделать. Например, добавить код или что-то ещё, хотя лучше бы указать это в комментарии.

> Кажется, автор просто не способен программировать.

Недопустимо.

> Это не ваш код, вы его откуда-то стащили и выдаёте за свой.

Допустимо. Скорее всего это вообще констатация факта, например, со ссылкой на другой вопрос, откуда взят код. Ну или определено по другим признакам.

---

> Допустим, модератор отклоняет тревогу, что дальше делать будем?

Можно попробовать поставить ещё раз - обычно модератор не рассматривает тревогу повторно, а оставляет для других (хотя формально такого требования нет). Но вполне можно можно и в чате обсудить с модераторами.

Comment: Здесь важен такой момент: ваши комментарии относятся к *сути* предложенных фраз или к их конкретной формулировке? Считаете ли вы правильным, что в первом комментарии используются такие резкие слова как `вообще`, если можно написать вежливее: `Расскажите, что вы сами думаете об этой проблеме` или `Советую добавить в вопрос ваши собственные размышления/мысли`. И еще вопрос: а если во втором примере ссылки **нет**! Комментатор просто заявляет: "Это не ваш код, вы его стащили откуда-то из интернета, поэтому не понимаете, и выдаете его за собственный код!"

Comment: @МаксимФисман, конкретную формулировку можно оценивать только в конкретном диалоге. Да, можно сказать вежливее, но если по какой-то причине этого не произошло, то надо бы на эту причину посмотреть. Мне кажется крайне маловероятным, что подобная формулировка возникнет на пустом месте под нормальным вопросом. Что касается чужого кода - вообще-то задавать вопросы по чужому коду не запрещено и автор может спокойно сказать, что нашёл код. Если автор по какой-то причине выдаёт чужой код за свой, то по опыту могу сказать, что это не только обман, но и обычно какая-то форма манипуляции сообществом.

Comment: @МаксимФисман Третье - иногда мое. Конкретная ситуация: достаточно *сложный для начинающего* код, в котором есть и циклы, и вывод значений переменных, только и того, что переменная-аккумулятор выводится в цикле, а не после него. И вопрос - как вывести значение только один раз? Скажите, у вас не возникнет подозрения, что код - чужой? Просто ТС хочется приспособить его к своей задаче? И что человек *совершенно не понимает и ничего не делал* - так что вопрос по-хорошему должен быть закрыт с формулировкой "Учебные задания... и далее по тексту"? Вы считаете это оскорбительным?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Да и первое... Навскидку пример не приведу, но часто надо просто глянуть в учебник и узнать, что для умножения используется оператор *, например. На ruSO постоянно постулируется польза для других от такого вопроса. **Какая** польза от такого вопроса? Для других? Если человек до такой степени лентяй, что пишет такие вопросы вместо чтоб в учебник глянуть - то он точно не будет поиск на ruSO проводить :)

Comment: @МаксимФисман Должен быть какой-то минимальный уровень вопросов. Иначе будет ситуация - сайт, посвященный высшей математике, завален вопросами "я в математике начинающий, не пинайте, но у меня контрольная - сколько будет 7 умножить на 8?" Так мы до мышей дотрахаемся, простите уж за анекдот...

Comment: @Harry Я не понял, спорите вы или высказываете параллельную точку зрения, но хочу отметить, что я не "за" подобные вопросы. Если вопрос совсем детский или наоборот сложнейший код и вопрос "А почему у меня ошибка "переменная не объявлена"?", то, конечно, с такими вопросами надо что-то делать (не конкретно такие, но это пример). Однако я про другое. Любая фраза должна быть вежливой, чтобы не оттолкнуть новичков сайта (даже если они и новички в программировании).. В первом комменте я привел замену первой фразы на более вежливые...

Comment: ...**Зачем** давить этим "ВООБЩЕ ДУМАЛИ?" Как в подворотне: *Слышь, ты че тут ваще, ты с какого района? Ты ВАЩЕ ДУМАЕШЬ куда тебя занесло?*  Насчет второй фразы... Ну, на мой взгляд, не всем будет приятно если им скажут так. Для меня это похоже на: `Кажется, автор вопроса д***л!` А насчет третьего, согласен с вами, он более адекватный, чем первые два. Возможно  все же стоило бы изменить стиль речи, но хоть так. НО! Потом должно идти еще что-то! Не просто `Это не ваш код`, а *хотя бы*: `погуглите`, `почитайте`, `советую удалить вопрос`. Чтобы комментарий нес хоть какой-то практический смысл:)

Comment: @МаксимФисман Чтобы человек в следующий раз подумал сам, прежде чем отвечать, а не считал, что это тут такой сайт, где все за тебя сделают, манной кашкой накормят и еще и в попку поцелуют, так что можно самому и не работать... Зачем? Есть же куча лохов на ruSO, которые только и мечтают, чтоб за кого-то ДЗ сделать...

Comment: @Harry Ну да, верно. Похоже, в итоге наши мнения сошлись:)

Comment: @МаксимФисман Вот, [свежий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1255875/195342). Если этот код написан автором вопроса - то вы верите, что он, написав подсчет букв, не в состоянии написать подсчет цифр? Готов спорить, что код - какого-то соседа по парте :), который он не в состоянии переделать под свою задачу...

Answer (score 5):

**Нет, неприемлемо.**

Флаг на **комментарий**: *"Он недружелюбен или враждебен"* более чем обоснован.

Флаг на **ответ**: *"Невежливый или оскорбительный"*, если ответ почти целиком состоит из таких тирад, либо сделать правку\предложение правки самостоятельно, если нужно удалить одно предложение. Также, при **систематическом** нарушении, возможно стоит поднять флаг *"Требуется вмешательство модератора"* с объяснением ситуации.

---

Обоснование — [Нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct):

> **Никаких резких замечаний или враждебно настроенных фраз.**
>
> Какими бы ни были ваши намерения, подобное поведение может негативно отразиться на ваших коллегах.

и конкретнее:

> **Никаких переходов на личности или личных выпадов.**
>
> Сосредоточьтесь на содержимом, а не на личности. Не используйте слова, связанные с человеческими качествами (например, «ленивый»), даже если ими можно описать содержание сообщения

Все три комментария из вопроса, на мой взгляд, безапелляционно подпадают под данную характеристику. Каждый из них без ущерба для дискуссии может (и должен) быть удален. Каждая из мыслей, выраженная в этих комментариях, либо не несет абсолютно ничего "разумного, доброго, вечного" и ей, пожалуй, стоит остаться в голове автора, либо она должна быть корректно и дружелюбно сформулирована.

Comment: _если только одно предложение нужно удалить._ - было [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/186999) и в итоге решили полностью удалять, а не редактировать комментарии.

Comment: @Grundy для этого и разделил на действия по комментариям и по ответам.

Comment: Интересно, не увидел разделения :)

Comment: Ответ может править любой участник - нафига в этой схеме модератор? Я бы вполне мог отклонить, даже если правка действительно нужна.

Comment: @Qwertiy чуть поправил сценарий.

Comment: Да, так правильнее.