# Редактирование комментариев модератором: какие правки вы считаете допустимыми?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии

Обычные участники не имеют возможности редактировать комментарии, которые написаны более 5 минут назад. А редактировать чужие комментарии не могут вовсе. Свои комментарии можно удалить в любой момент и написать новый, но если после удалённого уже написан какой-то другой комментарий, то может нарушиться причинно-следственная связь.

Модератор обладает возможностью не только удалить комментарий любого участника, но и отредактировать любой комментарий по месту. История правок комментария обычным участникам недоступна, есть только признак того, что комментарий был когда-то отредактиван определённое кол-во раз.

Я стараюсь не злоупотреблять возможностью правки комментариев, но несколько раз удалял некоторые части, которые ссылались на другие (уже ненужные и удалённые) комментарии, чтобы сохранить адекватность цепочки видимых комментариев.

В связи с этим у меня появился вопрос: какие правки вы считаете допустимыми делать модератору в комментариях других участников?

Comment: Не [такие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7140) )

Comment: @andreymal обещаю ваш "хрен" не трогать!

Comment: Я б ответил, но меня не спрашивали. :)

Comment: @aepot стал модератором - лишили права голоса)

Comment: @Danis я отредактировал комментарий. Заметно? Допустимо?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вообще не вижу разницы. Что поменяли?

Comment: @Danis [немного](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2K4A.jpg)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хаха). Против таких правок не против. Только за. В прошлом году по русскому языку 3 вышла.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12702/548252 кто подчистил комментарии? :D

Comment: @PeterKolosov только модераторы это могут делать единолично.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я понял

Answer (score 6):

Выскажу свое мнение:

Редактировать допустимо в случаях улучшения отображения:

- Исправление орфографии(за собой часто замечаю, но не всегда сразу вижу и могу поправить)
- Правки комментария в части визуального оформления
- Возможно!!! Замена мата(и подобного) на ****, когда комментарий по делу, но немного хромает(выше "хрен" и "редька" уже упоминались, однако я о более "сильных" словах, т.к. порой, без хрена никуда)

Править сам комментарий, с удалением/заменой части фраз/слов/букв, не правильно, ибо не известно, какой смысл был вложен в тот или иной комментарий.

Если комментарий нарушает правила, удалять, не нарушает, не трогать.

Answer (score 4):

Редактировать сообщения (в том числе комментарии) можно только в том случае, если любой желающий может посмотреть историю изменений. И автор комментария должен получать уведомление об этом. Поэтому считаю допустимым только удаление комментариев модераторами.

Объясню, почему.
По крайней мере один мой комментарий был отредактирован. Узнал я об этом случайно, заглянув в ту тему много времени спустя. С редакцией не согласен. Теперь все, кто прочитают его, будут думать, что он мой. Но я этого не писал!

И ладно, если это просто замена "хрена" на "редьку". А если сбрендивший модер политический лозунг, призыв к насилию или просто глупую шутку вложит в чужое сообщение?

Comment: Вряд ли модератор будет заниматься политическими редисками, но если что-то подобное произойдёт — другие модераторы смогут это увидеть. Уведомление, вероятно, имело бы смысл. А еще, похоже, что признак редактирования именно модератором не помешает. То есть какой-то особенный карандашик.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хорошие идеи. Но все мы давно знаем, что до нас дела нет)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а кому ? я вот незнаю (поведайте). Вий сидит там где то высоко ? (и никто ему веки не открывает, чтоб он эти идеи заметил ?)

Comment: @Dev18 "а кому ?" --- никому.

Comment: ☹️☹️☹️☹️☹️исчерпывающе @АлексейШиманский "никто" правит сообществом? Или там множество и "никому" совсем совсем нет дела? Или это игра слов, чтоб закрыть дискур.

Comment: @Dev18 Зарубежной команде разработчиков и администрации. Тут до RuSO хотя бы уже существующие на EnSO обновления докатывались вовремя, а то о каких-то новых фичах говорить)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar наше/и сообщество/админы/модераторы не может/могут корректировать `источник кода`/ `code source` сайта ? Вы знаете как проходит иерархия запросов ? Если да(ПП), поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: @Dev18 Точно сказать не могу, конечно, но насколько я понял за почти 5 лет нахождения здесь, что доступа к коду нет ни у кого (из модеров точно, админов по сути нет русскоязычных, менеджером был Николай, но его буквально недавно сняли). Не помню такого, чтобы что-то появлялось сначала на ру-сегменте, вряд ли кто-то получит такие права (площадка единая, просто разбита на простраства, подозреваю, что доступа вот так легко к одной из частей и не сможет дать никто). Даже перевод иногда изменяется с трудом