# Спасибо, Николай!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, менеджер-сообщества

*Прошу простить за плохой перевод компьютером. Редактируйте, чтобы улучшить, если хотите!*

На данный момент [Николай Чабановский](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) здесь уже не модератор и не менеджер сообщества.

Николай создал этот сайт. До [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) был [ХэшКод](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328064500/http://hashcode.ru/) — сайт Николая. Он создал его для того, чтобы был [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) на русском языке.

Я вдохновлён тем, что он задержался на этом сайте еще на 8 лет **после** того, как он [стал частью Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/06/11/welcome-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-stack-overflow-in-russian/). Каждый раз, когда я видел, как Николай работает или говорит, я видел честного человека, чья надежда на свой народ не уменьшалась, даже если иногда он разочаровывался (возможно, иногда это чувство было взаимным).

Я не могу сказать, почему он стал частью [увольнений](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/10/a-message-from-prashanth-chandrasekar-ceo-stack-overflow/), но, я думаю, важно признать его вклад в создание и работу этого места, а также поблагодарить его за усилия на протяжении многих лет. Я приглашаю вас сделать то же самое.

Comment: На мой сугубо личный взгляд, если вы в оригинале пишите на английском, нет ничего страшного в том, чтобы добавить оригинальный текст после горизонтального разделителя. In my humble opinion, if you originally write in English, it's fine to provide the original text after a horizontal line.

Comment: @Shog9 You're welcome! But in the future, I would recommend that you post the text in English. Because it is easier to translate from English into Russian than to think where the translator translated the text badly. For example [original post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/12597/1) and the [translate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/12597/2)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @ezio - I've been away too long 

Comment: I'm some upset. But maybe someday we'll meet in person with Nicolas. Thank you very much, Nikolas!

Comment: И не плохо было бы добавить этот пост на [Русский язык Мета](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/), это же тоже был сайт Николая.

Comment: It is necessary to add this post to the [Русский Язык Мета](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/), it was also the site of Nikolai.

Comment: **Николай** КрасАУчЭк, от души БЛАГОДАРЮ!!!

Comment: про увольнения. можно ли считать, что это одна из первых волн, спровоцированных генеративными моделями? думаю да, а ещё думаю, что руководство избрало ложный курс, начав борьбу с ИИ. это заведомо проигрышный путь и первая волна увольнений это только цветочки. имею удовольствие быть лично знакомым с Николаем и уверен, что эта перемена пойдёт ему на пользу!

Comment: @Anatol *"имею удовольствие быть лично знакомым с Николаем и уверен, эта перемена пойдёт ему на пользу"* - что вы хотите этим сказать?

Comment: @Anatol Они не борются с ИИ, а скорее наоборот: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389262/

Answer (score 43):

#### У всего, у чего есть начало, есть и конец.

Вчера был мой последний день в компании Stack Overflow. Это было удивительное приключение длинной почти в 13 лет. Я бы хотел выразить слова благодарности всем тем, кто все это время помогал не сбиться с пути мне и нашему сообществу: [постоянным участникам сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users), [модераторам сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) и [своим коллегам](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/274323). Без вас ничего бы не было. <3

Мои контакты есть в [моем профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky). Буду рад поболтать за русскоязычное сообщество программистов в сообщениях или за чашечкой чая в кафе, если мы окажемся рядом =)

Для меня было честью работать для вас! До новых встреч в Интернете :)

Comment: Thank you Nicolas - best wishes for your next adventure! Hope you take some time to bicycle somewhere fun 

Comment: Удачи вам в новых делах!

Comment: Не хотите стать модератором нашего сообщества? :)

Comment: @EzioMercer Спасибо! С удовольствием! Но для этого надо в выборах победить =)

Comment: Отлично! Я думал вы уже не захотите этим заниматься. Как только будут выборы и будет выдвинута ваша кандидатура, я уверен вас изберут в первую очередь :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Николай! И удачи во всем.

Comment: Николай, удачи тебе в твоих начинаниях и спасибо за труды над этим сайтом!

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Николай! Хоть я и не знаю вас лично, но хочу поблагодарить вас за всю проделанную работу. У вас всё получится! | Thank you a lot, Nicolas Chabanovsky!

Comment: Спасибо! И удачи!

Comment: Удачи в новых начинаниях.

Comment: Поздравляю с увольнением! Наконец можно чем-то другим заняться!

Comment: Немного трогательно... 

Answer (score 17):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 15):

Мне не выпал шанс лично познакомиться с Николаем, но я безмерно ему благодарен, за то что он помог создать этот сайт. Я тут познакомился с очень многими опытными разработчиками и научился много чему новому. Пожалуй, это единственное лучшее место для русскоязычных разработчиков

Я не знаю насколько это возможно и поддержит ли сообщество и сам Николай эту идею, но я предлагаю избрать Николя к нам в модераторы :)

Comment: присоединяюсь к Вашим словам.

Comment: Согласен! Знаком с Николаем лично и считаю, что он имеет право быть почётным модератором ruSO!

Answer (score 14):

Я расстроен и также хочу сказать "Спасибо, Николай!"

Я имел удовольствие встретится с Николасом несколькими годами ранее. Во время прогулки по Барселоне, где он проводил свой отпуск, мы разговаривали о многих темах. Я был глубоко впечатлён его интересом, желанием изучать и особенно мне понравилось передача всего его опыта в Stack Overflow, чтобы улучшить сайт и то, как это помогло многим людям.

Николас, вы создали что-то огромное и я уверен, что вы продолжите делать великие вещи.

Всего наилучшего!