# Какова модель администрирования ru.stackoverflow.com после Николаса?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, stackoverflow, менеджер-сообщества

Пока Николас был менеджером сообщества, за ним были закреплены следующие полномочия (прошу дополнить, если что-то упустил):

- представление интересов регионального сообщества (то есть онлайн-сходки живых людей) на планёрках по развитию всего StackExchange;
- личное взаимодействие (поддержание networking-а) с модераторами как по знакомству, так и по предписанным механизмам;
- разрешение конфликтов между модераторами и пользователями без задействования огромного и потому медленного механизма уровня и масштаба всего StackExchange;
- изменение локальных настроек логики и оформления (либо возможность по-быстрому связаться с теми, кто их может изменить);
- организация встреч сообщества.

После [упразднения должности, привязанной исключительно к локализованному сайту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12700/208074), эти полномочия перешли другим людям, но я не смог найти подробности. Есть общая информация о менеджерах сообщества в целом ([Who is on the Community Management Team, and what does it do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/357761)), но она описывает работу в масштабах всей Сети, то есть глобальных.

Поэтому мне, как пользователю, отвечающему на вопросы, немного общающемуся в чате и бывшему на очной встрече в Петербурге благодаря физической возможности, важно знать:

- кому перешли эти полномочия,
- насколько эти люди вовлечены в местную жизнь,
- как с ними можно связываться (метамета и без того перегружена, обслуживая и глобальную стратегию, и  все сообщества сразу),
- по насколько мелким вопросам они готовы откликаться.

Comment: *(то есть онлайн-сходки живых людей)* ... и *организация встреч сообщества* а где можно статистику (архив, может статья есть где, или кто в блоге писал как что прошло как что обсуждали) посмотреть ? . и когда к примеру **была** последняя такая **встреча ?** //кто и как там может/мог участвовать?

Comment: @Dev18 посмотрите вопросы с меткой [meta-tag:встречи-сообщества]

Comment: @Зонтик 2019 это самое новое, или это архив

Comment: @Dev18 К сожалению - и архив, и самое новое. К сожалению, потому что встреч давно не было (участники-организаторы их ушли с сайта: Николай и Suvitruf)

Comment: @Зонтик ну с сайта, то они точно не ушли (а тут еще и шутка, про то, что это ведь 'облако'. как отсюда уйдешь), регулярно и комментарии и присутсвие видно, наверно в 2024 будет встреча, или 25, такое грех не повторить. а так спасибо, пошла почитаю архив)

Comment: @Dev18 я имел в виду перестали быть активными.

Comment: @Зонтик вря**Т**ли их устроит `антоним` вашего прилагательного. Зонтик, исправили так исправили

Comment: @Dev18 относительно "недавно" был [meta-tag:видеочат]. А оффлайн-встречи это в общем-то малоинтересное (для большинства) событие, потому что физически единицы участников могут посетить. В видеочатах хотя бы косвенно можно поучаствовать.

Answer (score 17):

Stack Overflow на русском лишился (выделенного) менеджера сообщества [уже давно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217) (около 5 лет назад). Поэтому особых изменений после увольнения Николая из Stack Overflow непосредственно на ruSO я бы не стал ждать. Последние 5 лет он занимался уже совсем другими делами. Хотя по старой памяти, да и по географической приближённости (хотя даже 5 лет назад участники ruSO уже были достаточно широко раскиданы по миру) к основной массе участников ещё проводились некоторые мероприятия ([встречи-сообщества](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) [видеочат](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82)), которые можно было так или иначе связать со Stack Overflow.

Вопросы, которые нельзя решить на местной Мете, можно (иногда даже нужно) постить на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Если требуется ответ от сотрудника компании (кого-то из команды менеджеров сообщества всей сети), нужно воспользоваться [формой обратной связи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) (ссылка есть на каждой странице внизу слева). Со своей стороны (будучи модератором), думаю, что смогу форсировать обсуждение/решение некоторых вопросов, которые нужно решать уровнем выше. Но для этого надо, чтобы команда сообщества реагировала на запросы от модераторов в более приоритетном режиме. На текущий момент я пока не могу как-то оценить эту скорость взаимодействия, всё же выборы модераторов прошли совсем недавно.