# Куда делась ссылка на Тур в знаке вопроса (правый верхний угол сайта)?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, тур

Если нажать на вопросик в верхнем левом углу сайта, то покажется список страниц, куда можно перейти, чтобы получить помощь в пользовании ruSO:

- Тур
- Справка
- Мета
- О нас

Но ссылка на тур куда-то исчезла:

[image: здесь нету страницы тура]

Но страница тура на месте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Может, тур обиделся из-за того, что в нём примером эталонного вопроса служит слишком широкий вопрос?

**UPD**: на enSO тоже тура нет. И на PЯ.

Пробовал на MSE искать, ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Оформил на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393737/339911)

Comment: На [MSE сотрудник написал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393877/1346379), что это действительно баг, и его скоро починят. Ждём.

Comment: Сотрудник, ага. Целый вице-президент. Других сократили.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [мы это ещё не забыли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12700/532877).

Comment: То было давно. Теперь [свежая волна.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ что-то всё хуже и хуже. [meta-tag:нытьё].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это был действительно баг, то есть ссылку не убирали специально. [Уже воспроизвели и починили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393877/1346379).