# Нет перевода об автоматическом преобразовании комментария в ответ. И почему ответ преобразовала система?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация, нет-в-transifex, самоответы

Сотрудник [опубликовал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393877/1346379) ответ на баг-репорте на MSE. Поскольку я до этого публиковал [аналогичный баг-репорт на нашей мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13066/532877), то решил написать в виде ответа о том, что скоро починят со ссылкой на ответ на MSE.

В результате система преобразовала мой ответ в [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13066/#comment56445_13066).

1. Почему? Вроде ответ длиннее 30 символов. И это в принципе ответ, ибо мы имеем дело с метой.
2. Нет перевода в уведомлении об этом:

[image: Скрин дефекта]

**UPD**: раз строки нет в transifex, то завёл баг-репорт на MSE:

- [Transifex missing a string about automatically converting answer to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394461/1346379)

Comment: Строки [нет в традуцире](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=answer%20has%20been%20auto). Надо заводить багу на MSE. Про длину пока не знаю, надо исследовать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ понял. Заведу в ближайшее время.

Comment: [Хотели справку поправить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/339911), но не успели.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [завёл на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394461/1346379)