Раньше было (намного) больше
Связанный вопрос: Раньше было больше?


200 вопросов в день! (1 апреля 2017).
250 вопросов в день! (30 мая 2018).


Теперь же - 50 вопросов в день:


Я периодически заглядываю в аналитику сайта (доступна начиная с 25k репутации), вижу спад активности, причем резкое падение началось примерно с февраля 2023.
График с января 2022 по октябрь 2024:

График за весь период, включая приватную бету (период верхнего графика обведен прямоугольником):

Почему именно начиная с февраля 2023 такой спад — не понятно. Возможно связано с распространением ChatGPT (появился в ноябре 2022, к февралю 2023 начал заметно оттягивать на себя пользователей?), возможно еще что-то.

Собственно вопрос/просьба:
Я хочу понять причину резкого падения, начавшегося с 2023 года. Моя гипотеза - это расцвет ChatGPT. Если это так, то подобная тенденция должна быть видна и в аналитике enSO примерно с того же времени. Если там такой тенденции нет, значит причины какие-то более локальные.
У меня нет достаточной репутации, чтобы самому посмотреть там аналитику enSO, возможно кто-то из участников сможет выложить скрины аналитики оттуда за все время существования и за аналогичный период с января 2022.
Скриншоты из esSO и ptSO (как в "старом" вопросе) тоже неплохо было бы посмотреть, но это не обязательно.

Я полагаю, что SE перестали заниматься SEO для RU.SO, и просто забросили сайт. Весь трафик чисто самостоятельный. По графикам видно, когда примерно активности по привлечению аудитории прекратились.

@aepot возможно, и как раз видя график с enSO можно было бы и эту гипотезу опровергнуть или подтвердить. Я оптимистично предполагаю, что поисковой трафик должен сам по себе приходить при наличии такого количества контента, как-то специально подкручивать ничего не нужно (главное не ломать).

"Почему именно начиная с февраля 2023 такой спад — не понятно. Возможно связано с распространением ChatGPT" скорее всего именно по этой причине, как раз к этому времени вышло обновление той самой версии "4o", если я не ошибаюсь

У меня нет 25К на enSO.

@Qwertiy, ну, совсем немного осталось, нужно поднажать)

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-so-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82

@SpaceResearcher, он раньше каждый год так "умирал", но в 2019 не было каких-то прямо явных признаков этого.

@insolor, я с вами согласен - умирает, тут приведена статистика, с ней не поспоришь

Годовой эффект СВО?

@avp, очень сомневаюсь

@insolor, ну, отношение к окружающим изменилось, вот тут это вылезло таким образом

@avp, не понимаю, про какое отношение вы говорите (какое отношение, кого к кому?) Чтобы настолько сильно и резко упала посещаемость - это должна быть разве что новая мобилизация, забравшая 60% айтишников (причем в 100% должны входить школьники и студенты)

Я про то, что возникает вопрос, а заслуживает ли теперь население этой территории, чтобы с ним делились знаниями (это про ответы)? Ну и потеря интереса к активной деятельности, наверняка имеет место, что выражается в уменьшении количества вопросов

@avp тут "не очень" место (вообще не место) для этого обсуждения, это уже в чат для политоты. Но я туда не захожу.

@insolor я тоже, самый необъективный чат на всем ruSO=) хотя раньше бывало заглядывал. По сути вопроса ТС, скорей всего это накопительный эффект всех факторов, связанные как с внутренними процессами в стране, так и внешними влияниями. Насколько я понял многие технологии просто ушли из страны и вопросы по ним не задаются здесь отныне.

А статистика посещений по странам в аналитике есть? Насчет английских сайтов, они снижение активности тоже заметили: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387278/370389 Если интересует количество вопросов, доступ к аналитике не нужен, можно запросами в data explorer анализировать.

Посмотрел еще раз на графики и хотел бы обратить внимание сообщества на конец первой четверти на графике количества вопросов-ответов за весь период. Обратите внимание в этой точке количество ответов стало меньше количества вопросов. Это безусловно не объясняет резкое падение февраля 23-го, но показывает, на мой взгляд, качественное изменение в обстановке на сайте. Что там произошло? Не знаю. Но, похоже именно с этого времени начался упадок тут

вопрос не в том отжал ли ~ГПТ аудиторию, а в том почему отжал?. а ответ... тут целый ворох классических форумных болячек, которые благодаря ГПТ теперь больше незачем терпеть. сравни UJM. СО: зайти, зарегаться, задать вопрос, получить кучу замечаний не решающих вопрос(любой шаблон из очереди проверок), устроить срач на мете, мол "а чо меня заминусили?" и тд.. ГПТ: вбить вопрос в первом попавшемся поисковике, сразу же получив ответ безо всяких срачей. кмк выбор очевиден. тут виной попытка усидеть на двух слабо совместимых стульях, я б даже сказал взаимоисключающих: и форум и база знаний

@puffleeck так у меня и нет вопроса "почему" gpt может отобрать аудиторию - это и так очевидно. Я пытаюсь для начала выяснить - это действительно gpt, или что-то вообще другое.

@insolor так у меня и нет вопроса "почему", это и так очевидно точно нету? `Собственно вопрос/просьба:
Я хочу понять *причину* резкого падения, начавшегося с 2023 года`, но впрочем да, телепат из меня так себе :3

@puffleeck еще раз: у меня нет вопроса почему именно chat gpt может быть причиной. Я хочу понять, это он или что-то вообще другое.

@avp есть статья недавняя от Николаса про то, как деятельность коммьюнити менеджера влияет на сообщество. Там 2017 год (когда вопросов стало задаваться больше, чем ответов) находится в середине периода активного менеджмента (2015-2019 примерно), чисто технически этот период - все еще период роста. Я не думаю, в 2017 году прямо что-то сломалось, скорее сайт уже собрал +- всех, кто мог быть активным "отвечающим", и дальше кто-то из них уходил, кто-то приходил (сохранялся баланс), а новые "вопрошающие" только приходили и приходили.

@avp там еще есть график притока-оттока участников, и он меня сбил немного, потому что там в конце какой-то гигантский отток, но оказалось что реальные данные там не ближе 1.5 года к текущему моменту можно адекватно оценить (в статье про это написано)

@avp, забыл ссылку вставить: https://practical-cm.com/t/does-having-a-community-manager-really-matter-and-how-can-we-measure-their-work/143

@insolor, спасибо, почитаю...

@MSDN.WhiteKnight по странам нет. Посмотрел вопрос на meta.stackexchange.com - там как будто по графикам не видно резкого падения (кроме графика голосов, но тут надо сопоставлять с аналогичным данными помесячно у нас), больше похоже на общий многолетний тренд. Возможно как раз ваше предположение про "нейро" в яндекс поиске верное, но нужно как-то понять, когда это прикрутили. ЯндексГПТ вроде как 17 мая 2023 года выпустили, по датам не совпадает, так что не все еще понятно.

@insolor, почитал документ от Николая, интересный график по категориям пользователей, но все равно мало информации для выводов, почему людям тут становится не интересно. Кстати, вы обратили внимание на 2 горба во всех графиках? Второй горб (хотя сайт был уже unmanaged в терминологии Николая) примерно совпадает с началом пандемии.

@avp, второй горб начинает расти в сентябре 2019, пик в мае 2020, дальше идет на спад. Это вряд ли напрямую с пандемией связано.

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12706/264178 падение началось примерно с февраля 2023 => а вот май 2023, в тот период ушел наш представитель ru.SO с головного офиса...

@Dev18, он фактически уже никак не взаимодействовал с ru.SO, его уход уже ничего не менял.

https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/893870#resultSets можно по дням посмотреть, пусть тут побудет

у меня не большой опыт, но хотелось бы поделиться мнением. Например на изи вопросы проще и быстрее получить ответ от gpt. Но ответы на более сложные или нестандартные вопросы (т.е. не факт что сложные, а сложные именно для меня) я ищу здесь. Таким образом я вижу это как фильтр вопросов по сложности или нестандартным ситуациям, что мне кажется наоборот хорошо.

@AlexMarch, интересная мысль, получается что меньше - не значит хуже


не обязательно хуже


2015-2024 2022-2024

@AlexMarch, "мне кажется наоборот хорошо" -- о чем вы говорите? Посмотрите на   предпоследний график из статьи Николая. Видите, уже в 2019 году количество сообщений от Regular users  (это те, кто писал от 5 до 12 posts per month) упало ниже трафика One time posters. А в 2023 вообще катастрофа -- основной трафик (и так невысокий) создают как раз One time posters, а сообщений от Core users (те кто постоянно пишет более 12 posts per month) стало совсем мало.

@avp про "сообщений от Core users стало совсем мало" это действительно волнительно. Я хз но получается если очень упрощенно, то надо взять пингануть и спросить всех Core users - "эй а почему от вас нет активности ? что изменилось ?"

@AlexMarch, вот и откройте тему

...а может все дело в том, что просто большую часть вопросов задали, и поэтому люди просто пользуются имеющейся в наличии базой(?) не создавая новые (что собственно и привело к спаду)

@Dev18, вряд ли. Была бы куча дубликатов вместо новых вопросов. Ну и это давало бы долгий медленный спад в течение многих лет, а не такой резкий.

То есть, можно уточнить? В январе 2023 прям 200 было, а в феврале сразу 50?//мне думается, что у нас тоже он долгий и медленный, судя по вопросам на мете... "" ru.SO умирает" и подобные...

@Dev18 в январские праздники 2022/2023 - ~1700 вопросов+ответов в неделю, потом пик в феврале 2023 - 2396 в неделю, потом начинается явный спад, в ближайшем локальном минимуме в июне - 1062 в неделю. Сейчас - 695 в неделю.

Непонятно, чем февраль 2023 выделен? Если тупо взять статистику новых вопросов, то для SO, ruSO и mathSO максимум был в мае 2020. И на настоящий момент количество новых вопросов уменьшилось: SO - 6,3 раза, ruSO - 4,5 раза, mathSO - 3,2 раза. Выделятся astronomySO: максимум - май 2021, спад - 3,1 раза, но там статистика мелкая.  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1717975/new-question-activity-per-month-since-2018#graph  ; ruSO - https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1717975/new-question-activity-per-month-since-2018#graph ;

@Serge3leo февраль 2023 отличается тем, что там виден явный излом долговременного тренда. Медленное многолетнее снижение (ну или циклы подъем/спад) сменились резким падением.

@insolor , да, на ruSO, SO и mathSO наблюдалась яма с февраля по ноябрь 2023  (на mathSO с апреля). По крайней, мере статистика "новых вопросов" начиная с ноября 2023 подросла и вернулась на уровень продолжения долговременного тренда. Т.е., ответственное за эту яму, конкурентное для SO/ruSO/mathSO "хобби" было актуально только в феврале-ноябре 2023. Как бы, не очень похоже на ChatGPT, но...

@Serge3leo, я не вижу, чтобы что-то вернулось. Ни на ruSO, ни на enSO. Не видно никакого возвращения, ни на графиках в вопросе, ни вот на графиках с enSO: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14381/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment59455_14381

@insolor и на ваших диаграммах виден же возврат к основному тренду. Для новых вопросов: https://i.yapx.ru/YIRKv.png

@Serge3leo на моих графиках нет никакого возврата. Графики до октября 2024.

@insolor , статистика то, одна. Правда, чувствительность параметров разная, но думаю "новые вопросы" не хуже других. Просто проведите линии долговременного тренда на тех графиках или на этих: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1717975/new-question-activity-per-month-since-2018#graph ; https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1717975/new-question-activity-per-month-since-2018#graph ; https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1717975/new-question-activity-per-month-since-2018#graph

@Serge3leo я долговременный тренд смотрю на данных за все время, с 2015 года. Сравните что было до 2023 и 2023-2024: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/1871003#graph

@insolor , к сожалению мои слова "вернулась на уровень продолжения долговременного тренда", увы, далеки от оптимизма. Поскольку долговременный тренд это: SO(enSO) -60%/год, ruSO -40%/год, mathSO -30%/год

@insolor , ну да, и на нём долговременный тренд с марта-апреля 2020 по настоящее время ≈  -40%/год и в этом тренде яма в феврале-ноябре 2023 примерно ещё на -25%. Яма кончилась, а тренд, увы, сохранился. В 2021 похожая посадка, по-мельче.

Помимо непосредственно ChatGPT, интересен еще один фактор. У Яндекса появился некий "поиск с нейро", который прямо перед результатами поиска выводит сгенерированный нейросетью ответ на запрос, основанный на нескольких наиболее релевантных источниках:

Притом среди перечисленных источников русского Stackoverflow вообще нету, хотя вопросов по сортировке массивов в С++ у нас вагоны. Также Яндекс стал куда чаще автоматически переводить английские тексты на русский язык и вставлять в результаты поиска выше русскоязычных сайтов. Сам перевод тоже усовершенствован с помощью нейросетей, так что он стал больше напоминать человеческий русский текст. Эти нововведения весьма вероятно оказали негативное влияние на переходы по многим сайтам из поиска. Так что предположение, что дело в ChatGPT, не лишено оснований, хотя вряд ли пользователи осознанно вместо сайта идут на ChatGPT, скорее сам интернет меняется под ее влиянием.

Вот это похоже на реальную причину оттока. Я помню, что был период до всяких GPT, когда Яндекс практически не показывал ruSO в выдаче, и это было проблемой. По-моему Николас тут на Мете про это писал.

Из того что можно предположить:

Отрасль серъезно пострадала, а год это такой срок, когда острое переходит в хроническое: те разработчики, которые временно выехали, перестают ориентироваться на возвращение, следовательно, перестают ориентироваться на ruSO.

Спад вопросов о ЕГЭ. Раньше были вопросы от школьников, теперь, возможно, экзамены устаканились, ученики переключены на более специализированные ресурсы, которые их натаскивают по прошлогодним программам. Это хорошо согласуется с февралем, когда начинают готовится к ЕГЭ.

Международные олимпиады перестали быть привлекательны для школьников РФ. Это летнее занятие. Теперь школьники весной не готовятся к разным летним событиям.

Те же сроки что и в первом пункте, мы теряем украинскую русскоговорящую часть ruSO. Тоже острое переходит в хроническое.


Со школьниками - плохо. Это будущая аудитория, которую мы теряем.
Выше нос! Чтобы ресурс раскрутился обратно, когда ситуация станет лучше, он должен к этому быть готов. У сайтов "вопрос/ответ" отличная позиция, если они заполнены качественным содержимым. Пока тут есть 20-50-100 специалистов, готовых отвечать, тенденция может быть развёрнута обратно в течении одного года.

Не похоже. Это бы скорее дало постепенный дальнейший спад, но не резкий спад в 2023. Перелом в 2023 году - это включение какого-то нового значительного фактора. Пока что подозрение на ChatGPT.

На первом графике видны просадки в феврале и октябре 2022, они вполне объяснимы, но каждый раз было восстановление. В начале 2023 не было никаких подобный потрясений, которые были объяснить такой спад. Подозрение все еще на ChatGPT.

@insolor, мой ответ ограничем моими знаниями (неожиданно, но факт). Я плохо представляю ситуацию с chatGPT и его доступностью на русском языке. Потому его нет в ответе.

Ситуация такая, что сейчас условному школьнику проще задать вопрос ChatGPT или его аналогу (от яндекса или сбера, например), чем идти на SO.

@insolor, я не возражаю, но хочу календарной привязки. В феврале что-то опубликовали? Встроили в поисковик? В VisualCode? Открыли доступ с мобилок?

Вот это не понятно. Моя гипотеза в том, что он стал доступен в ноябре 2022, и уже с того времени начал давать спад, но который в итоге стал очевиден только в феврале 2023. Могло быть наложение какого-то временного подъема на SO и спада из-за GPT, в итоге подъем закончился, и на графике получился резкий спад.

@insolor, нужен специалист, который разложит график на моды? А мы тогда будем про разные моды рассуждать. Но, подозреваю что что-то должно объединять chatGPT и февраль 2023 в одной фразе. Или Гугл снизил ruSO в выдаче в феврале? Нужны рыночные аналитики.

1ое очень спорное утверждение. Удобство общения на русском, для выехавших и не думающих возвращаться, все равно актуально. По себе знаю, хотя я бы уехал обратно. Я уехал много раньше всех этих событий. 4ое тоже кажется надуманным. Мало здесь ребят/девчат с Украины? Когда ищешь решение вопроса, вряд ли тебя интересуют внутренние переживания связанные с этим

"мы теряем украинскую русскоговорящую часть ruSO", а SO теряет украинскую англоговорящую часть?! Если с мая 2020 число новых вопросов ruSO уменьшилось в 4,6 раза, а SO в 6,3 раза.

Несмотря на то, что участником сайта Stack Overflow на русском я являюсь почти 2 года, всё же активным пользователем я могу себя назвать только последние 1,5 месяца. Тем не менее этого времени мне хватило для того, чтобы сделать определённые выводы.
Безусловно, будет трудно оспорить тот факт, что GPT изменил "правила игры". На мой взгляд, именно он и привёл к такому результату.
Закономерное снижение активности пользователей с 2023 года другими причинами объяснить не могу (ограничен своими знаниями в этой области ¯_(ツ)_/¯), поскольку именно тогда произошёл "бум" нейронки. Кто о ней теперь не знает? А ведь до 2022 о ней и никто особо не слышал (кроме особо интересующихся).
Раньше мы все смеялись с того, какие неуклюжие фото и видео удаётся сгенерировать с помощью неё. Теперь же становится не очень смешно ._. Виден колоссальный прогресс, и с этим спорить трудно.
Возвращаясь к теме: сейчас людям проще задать тупой вопрос "в лоб", "написать" код, "создать" модели, ассеты "с нуля" с помощью GPT.
Зачем тратить время и силы на формулирование вопроса, если можно сказать GPT: "Напиши код ТГ бота, который..." — и он всё сделает.

Что я хочу этим сказать:

Переживать по поводу "умирания сайта" не стоит. Мне кажется, что происходит закономерный процесс отделения "зёрен" от "плевел". Да, есть и такая тенденция, что на сайте задают вопросы по типу "как дышать" (я смягчил аллегорию из ответа другого автора по другому вопросу)) ), но можно ли сказать, что на сайте своего рода не "зарождаются" начинающие звёзды программирования? Навряд ли.

Заменит ли нейронка программистов целиком специалистов со Stack Overflow? Надо быть нездоровым человеком, чтобы сказать "Да". Кто ещё может так детально вникнуть в проблематику вопрошающего? Не только ответить на вопрос, но и дать дельный совет/лайфхак, а также предоставить сборку ресурсов, которые помогут человеку развиться в нужном ему направлении? Нейронка что ли? Ха-ха.

Нужно продолжать то, что все мы умеем делать — задавать качественные вопросы и давать качественные ответы. Вот не раз видел в ленте вопросы и ответы от профессионалов, которые "взрывают мозг". Где я (да и вы) узнали бы о них? На каком ресурсе? На другом? — Возможно, но именно Stack Overflow этим и ценится, этого у него не отнять.



В завершение своей мысли я не могу не привести цитату из ответа @Stanislav Volodarskiy:

Выше нос! Чтобы ресурс раскрутился обратно, когда ситуация станет лучше, он должен к этому быть готов. У сайтов "вопрос/ответ" отличная позиция, если они заполнены качественным содержимым. Пока тут есть 20-50-100 специалистов, готовых отвечать, тенденция может быть развёрнута обратно в течении одного года.


Если статистика относится только к русскому сообществу, то наверное дело не только в ChatGPT или SEO, но и в том комьюнити, которое тут есть, в тех традициях, которые сложились на ruSO.
Многие участники сидят здесь не для того, чтобы создать полезную базу знаний, а для того, чтобы строго следовать правилам, которые не до конца формализованы. Почти каждый сталкивался с удалением, закрытием объективно полезного вопроса (не обязательно своего), который приходилось отстаивать потом здесь.
Многие сталкивались с баном "за твинки или накрутку голосов", хотя часто это просто ошибка, например чужой аккаунт ложно распознан как фальшивый и участнику вообще непричастному прилетел бан или коллега с офиса лайкнул пару твоих постов (а у вас в офисе внешний айпишник одинаковый).
ruSO не просто так носит репутацию очень токсичного сообщества, много идей было предложено на мете по поводу интеграции новичков и что в итоге? Да ничего, все заходят написать: "это задание с вашей лабы?" или "прикрепите код не картинкой", а не для того, чтобы помочь. Я почти полностью отказался от использования ruSO именно по причине сообщества, очень немного людей здесь, которые хотят следовать первичной идее - сделать базу знаний, полезную и нужную, сильно больше тех, кто служит правилам, которые могут иметь разную трактовку.
Все эти вопросы поднимались не раз здесь и на Хабре (невероятное количество вопросов просто о правилах поведения, взаимодействия и тп), много раз обсуждались, но решений принято не было или почти не было. ruSO сам избрал свой путь

То что вы описываете было всегда, и никак не объясняет значительный отток с начала 2023 года. До 2023 года был какой-то баланс, но потом что-то его сломало.

@insolor, вовсе нет, сейчас средний возвраст разработчика сильно ниже, чем 5-10 лет назад. Современное поколение воспитано иначе, оно вырасло в других условиях и текущий формат, правила и традиции не привлекают молодых ребят,что не удивительно, вот по этой причине тут в основном и могли остаться старечки

Смена поколений тоже не объясняет резкое падение начиная с 2023 года.

резкое - нет, тенденцию да, ско постройте и моду, видно будет, что глобально руСо идёт на спад

Да общая тенденция мне понятна, и она в принципе объяснима многими причинами. К смене поколений, правда, я бы это не привязывал все равно.

Т.е. общая долговременная тенденция понятна, не на 100% понятен резкий отток с 2023

-1. Не согласен почти по по всем пунктам. Очевидно из вилки плохая ложка, если использовать её как ложку, а не по назначению.

Сегодня часто слышу от коллег, что моя документация четкая, понятная, легкая. И времени на её написание уходит гораздо меньше. Полтора года назад я тратила часы на формулировки и правки. Во многом этому способствовал именно ru.SO. Одно из ключевых качеств программиста — ясно излагать мысли, будь то код, задача или документация. Даже если код исправляют и критикуют (код картинкой-да это плохо), со временем за это можно сказать только «спасибо». Критика может казаться болезненной, особенно в моменте, но если оставить эмоции, ru.SO — отличная площадка для роста.

@Dev18 тут мой код никто особо не критиковал(( зато критиковали за "слишком общие" вопросы, которые на самом деле не нарушают правил

В общем, похоже на правду, но настоящая причина глубже

Space Researcher, что это дало? Как итог? Вы стали (не обязательно здесь) разбивать ваш вопрос на ПОДвопросы, чтоб не был общим, либо только обида и отказ от стековерфлоу как следствие? А может, тот кто криитиковал ошибался? Из за одного, теперь все сообщество отвечает? Мне попадались ваши ответы/вопросы, а если я запоминаю ник, значит там было явно что то интересное. полностью отказался от использования ruSO => а что было раньше, как именно вы пользовались, что для вас ru.SO в идеале.
